# How to replace innerHTML of a div using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, innerhtml

How could I achieve the following:

```
document.all.regTitle.innerHTML = 'Hello World';
```

Using jQuery where `regTitle` is my `div` id?

Comment: Funny how people still grasp on to vanilla js even when you ask for the answer in jquery...

Answer (score 1798, accepted):

```
$("#regTitle").html("Hello World");
```

Answer (score 355):

The [html()](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/html#val) function can take strings of HTML, and will effectively modify the `.innerHTML` property.

```
$('#regTitle').html('Hello World');
```

However, the [text()](http://api.jquery.com/text) function will change the (text) value of the specified element, but keep the `html` structure.

```
$('#regTitle').text('Hello world');
```

Comment: " but keep the html structure" . can you explain?

Comment: From the jQuery API documentation (http://api.jquery.com/text/), `text()` is different as: `Unlike the .html() method, .text() can be used in both XML and HTML documents.`. Furthermore, according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910794/what-is-the-difference-between-jquery-text-and-html, `jQuery.html() treats the string as HTML, jQuery.text() treats the content as text`.

Comment: @AnoopJoshi http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910794/what-is-the-difference-between-jquery-text-and-html

Answer (score 86):

If you instead have a jQuery object you want to render instead of the existing content: Then just reset the content and append the new.

```
var itemtoReplaceContentOf = $('#regTitle');
itemtoReplaceContentOf.html('');
newcontent.appendTo(itemtoReplaceContentOf);
```

Or:

```
$('#regTitle').empty().append(newcontent);
```

Comment: Good place to use `itemtoReplaceContentOf.empty();`

Comment: Is ``newcontent`` is a jQuery object? This isn't clear.

Comment: @kmoser In the first example, newcontent is indeed a jquery object. In the second example it can be of type `htmlString` or `Element` or `Text` or `Array` or `jQuery` as per http://api.jquery.com/append/

Answer (score 29):

Here is your answer:

```
//This is the setter of the innerHTML property in jQuery
$('#regTitle').html('Hello World');

//This is the getter of the innerHTML property in jQuery
var helloWorld = $('#regTitle').html();
```

Answer (score 15):

**Answer:**

```
$("#regTitle").html('Hello World');
```

**Explanation:**

`$` is equivalent to `jQuery`. Both represent the same object in the jQuery library. The `"#regTitle"` inside the parenthesis is called the **selector** which is used by the jQuery library to identify which element(s) of the html DOM (Document Object Model) you want to apply code to. The `#` before `regTitle` is telling jQuery that `regTitle` is the id of an element inside the DOM.

From there, the dot notation is used to call the **html** function which replaces the inner html with whatever parameter you place in-between the parenthesis, which in this case is `'Hello World'`.

Answer (score 15):

There are already answers which give how to change Inner HTML of element.

But I would suggest, you should use some animation like Fade Out/ Fade In to change HTML which gives good effect of changed HTML rather instantly changing inner HTML.

## Use animation to change Inner HTML

```
$('#regTitle').fadeOut(500, function() {
    $(this).html('Hello World!').fadeIn(500);
});
```

If you have many functions which need this, then you can call common function which changes inner Html.

```
function changeInnerHtml(elementPath, newText){
    $(elementPath).fadeOut(500, function() {
        $(this).html(newText).fadeIn(500);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 12):

you can use either html or text function in jquery to achieve it

```
$("#regTitle").html("hello world");
```

OR

```
$("#regTitle").text("hello world");
```

Answer (score 11):

jQuery's `.html()` can be used for setting and getting the contents of matched non empty elements (`innerHTML`).

```
var contents = $(element).html();
$(element).html("insert content into element");
```

Comment: The open and close parenthesis after html saved me. So remember folks those two are important.

Answer (score 11):

**Example**

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('.msg').html('hello world');
});
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>    
      </head>
      <body>
        <div class="msg"></div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 6):

```
$("#regTitle")[0].innerHTML = 'Hello World';
```

Answer (score 6):

### Pure JS and Shortest

Pure JS

```
regTitle.innerHTML = 'Hello World'
```

```js
regTitle.innerHTML = 'Hello World';
```

```html
<div id="regTitle"></div>
```

Shortest

```
$(regTitle).html('Hello World');
```

```js
// note: no quotes around regTitle
$(regTitle).html('Hello World');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="regTitle"></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Just to add some performance insights.

A few years ago I had a project, where we had issues trying to set a large HTML / Text to various HTML elements.

It appeared, that "recreating" the element and injecting it to the DOM was way faster than any of the suggested methods to update the DOM content.

So something like:

```js
var text = "very big content";
$("#regTitle").remove();
$("<div id='regTitle'>" + text + "</div>").appendTo("body");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Should get you a better performance. I haven't recently tried to measure that (browsers should be clever these days), but if you're looking for performance it may help.

The downside is that you will have more work to keep the DOM and the references in your scripts pointing to the right object.

Answer (score 3):

jQuery has few functions which work with text, if you use `text()` one, it will do the job for you:

```
$("#regTitle").text("Hello World");
```

Also, you can use `html()` instead, if you have any **html tag**...

Answer (score 1):

```
var abc = document.getElementById("regTitle");
abc.innerHTML = "Hello World";
```

Comment: the question is regarding JQUERY - NOT - Javascript!