# set text in jquery

Tags: jquery

If I want to set the text of a `<div id="error"></div>` to "Test message here", do I do:

```
 $('<div id="error">').text('Test message here');
```

I tried this and it's not working.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You create a new div and set its text, but you don't insert it anywhere. What you need to do is:

```
var el = $('<div id="error">').text('Test message here');
$(document).append(el);
```

or, if the div is already there:

```
$("#error").text('Test message here');
```

Answer (score 28):

```
 $('#error').text('Test message here');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$('<div id="error"></div>').text('Test message here');
```

You also need to insert the new element somewhere in the page.

Answer (score -4):

It's preferable to use

```
$("#error").html('Test message here')
```

instead of simply

```
.text('Text Msg');
```

Comment: needs to little more explanation.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13910604/3132099 - Please check this for a detailed explanation