# Change text after scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello I got a question regarding changing a text after a user scrolled the page.

How can I change the text of my `h1` from YES to NO when a user scrolled?I have tried several things like `.append()`, `.html()` but with no succes.

My code: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/m1oasnkg/2/)

**HTML**

```
<h1>YES</h1>

<article style="height: 1000px">
    <p>test</p>
</article>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
            //change yes to no
        } else {
            //set h1 text to yes
        }
    });
});
```

The reason I want this is because in the case of using `.html()`, I can add inline html objects like: `.html('<span>yes</span>')`

Comment: possible duplicate of [set text in jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4511804/set-text-in-jquery)

Comment: that is not a duplicate of what I am asking @Glorfindel

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try this

the [WORKING FIDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/v4vishnuprasad/m1oasnkg/3/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) { 
            //change yes to no
            $('h1').html('No');
        } else {
            //set h1 text to yes
            $('h1').html('Yes');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
<h1 id="h1">YES</h1>


$(document).ready(function () {

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
            $("#h1").text("NO");
            //change yes to no
        } else {
            $("#h1").text("YES");

            //set h1 text to yes
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You shouldn't really have to add an ID/Class to the H1, as you are only supposed to have one on a page

Answer (score 3):

You can try this with much optimized code:

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  $('h1').html($(this).scrollTop() > 100 ? 'Yes':'No');
}).scroll(); //<---triggers the scroll on load
```

```css
body{height:1200px;}
h1{position:fixed;} /* <---for example only i positioned it fixed.*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1></h1>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make yours element position fixed and then try this logic

HTML

```
<h1 id="yy" style="position:fixed">YES</h1>

<article style="height: 1000px">
    <p>test</p>
</article>
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
           $("#yy").text("NO")
        } else {
            $("#yy").text("YES")
        }
    });
});
```

[JSFIDDEL](http://jsfiddle.net/m1oasnkg/10/)

Hope it will help

Comment: You shouldn't really have to add an ID/Class to the H1, as you are only supposed to have one on a page

Comment: Thanks for suggestion