# How would I sanitize this string? (preferably in JQuery)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a webpage where people type stuff into a text box, and it displays that text below them.  That's it. There is no server side.

Let's say someone types `<script src="blah">hello</script>`

I want to display that as text. Not as a script, of course. How can I do that (all in javascript)?

I want to display the entire text. Don't stip the tags out.

Comment: then use `var txt = $('div').text();` Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910794/what-is-the-difference-between-jquery-text-and-html

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
$('div.whatever').text($('input.whatever').val());
```

That'll convert things to HTML entities, so they're displayed as they were typed, and not treated as markup.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display it in an element, you can use the [`text` method](http://api.jquery.com/text). It will escape all the HTML for you.

**You can see an example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dRnC4/).**

Comment: @TIMEX: It escapes it, not deletes it.

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="text" onkeyup="$('#outputDiv').text($(this).val());" />
<div id="outputDiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick way to sanitize any string in general with JQuery would be create a temporary element, set the text content with the `text` method and then retrieve the escaped text with `text` again.

```
const unsanitized = '<script>alert()></script>'

// Outputs '<\script>alert()><\/script>'
const sanitized = $("<p>").text(unsanitized).text()
```