# Replacing HTML with Javascript in a way that is executable in a browser

Tags: javascript, html, replace

I have no Javascript experience at all. What I want is to replace a single instance of a block of text in a page's HTML - how can I do this?

30 minutes of reading around has brought me this:

```
javascript:document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace("this","that");
```

Am I even close?

Comment: It is close. But where did you put this line? You will need to execute it, how did you (try to) do that? Maybe you should read some further. JavaScript is a totally diffent concept from HTML (it is actual programming), and you don't usually learn it in half an hour.

Comment: The Firefox address bar. I'm not making an effort to learn it, honestly, I just have a use for this script in mind.

Comment: I suppose that he has that line in example into onclick="". Something like that onclick="javascript:document.body.innerHTML = 'that'"

Comment: FWIW "`javascript:` URLs" don't run in the page's context since FF6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
javascript:document.body.innerHTML = "that"
```

Comment: Also, note that I want to replace a block of text within innerHTML, not innerHTML itself.

Comment: @RobertoC.: Assigning a value to innerHTML *is* the way to replace text in an element. Any element, including `body`. (Well, it's *a* way. There are many others.)

Comment: Then you have to describe what you want to do. The above example describes exactly that thing. That you want to replace the body content it self.

Comment: For better solution show us the HTML part you want to change (ie: <div id="testarea"><p>This is what I like to change</p></div>) and we will show you many options ;) That's the best

Answer (score 2):

With no experiance at all I recommend you take a look at [jQuery](http://query.com). With jQuery you can do:

Given:

```
<p>block of text</p>
```

jQuery:

```
$('p').text("some other block of text");
```

Comment: Ha with all my exp with jquery I woulda thought you would have to do `$('p').html('the text');` +1 for teaching me something new lol

Comment: @Atticus `$.html()` differs from `$.text()`, they both have their own applicability.

Comment: @Shef cool, ill have to go read up on that, im assumig text() will insert / get plain text, no code

Comment: @Atticus [jQuery: text() vs html()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910794/jquery-text-vs-html) will give you a rough idea. The main observable difference is that `$.text()` will encode special chars to their entities, thus making it possible for the HTML markup to be displayed not rendered.

Answer (score 1):

1) If it is part of a URL, such as `<a href="...">`, then you need
`javascript:void(document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace("this","that"));`

2) If it is part of an event, such as `<button onClick="...">`, then you need
`document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace("this","that");`

3) If you are trying to replace ALL instances of "this" with "that", and not just the first, then you need
`... .replace(/this/g,"that")`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot just execute that script in the address bar. It needs to operate on a document, but there is nothing to replace there. Executing javascript from the address bar will give you a new empty document on which that code operates.

Even if you try to load a document from javascript, the rest of your script gets executed first. Try this:

```
javascript:window.location='http://www.google.com';alert(document.innerHTML);
```

You'll see that the alert pops up before the page is loaded, and it shows 'undefined'.

Even when you try binding to the onload event of the document or the window it won't work. Probably because they are reset afterwards.

```
javascript:window.location='http://www.google.com';window.onload=function(){alert(document.innerHTML);};
```

And it makes sense; if this would work, you could manipulate the next page when jumping to that page, thus making it possible to inject javascript in a page you link to. That would be a big security issue, so it's a good thing this doesn't work.