# case sensitive text replace in Jquery

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Jquery: Find Text and replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8146648/jquery-find-text-and-replace)

I am Using latest jQuery library with html.I want to replace all occurrences of text "Cat" with "Man" in an whole html file using jQuery, exactly the word only **case sensitively**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm..

jQuery Version :

```
$('body').html($('body').html().replace(/\bCat\b/g, 'Man'));
```

Pure JavaScript version :

```
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/\bCat\b/g, 'Man');
```

Comment: This definitely works so you have my upvote, but I wonder if the OP is aware of potential side effects: http://jsfiddle.net/Vzahb/2

Comment: Oops, forgot about that, fixed it now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to replace the words in the `<title>` tag even because when you say whole html file those also are included,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("*").each(function () {
    if ($(this).children().length == 0) {
        $(this).text($(this).text().replace('Cat','Man'));
    }
 });
});
```