# jquery replace string in anchor by using regex

Tags: javascript, jquery

In class="listing" all li a with string "-p." should be replaced to " / p. " eg. "1r-p.1_1" should be converted to "1r / p. 1_1".

current situation:

```
<ul class="listing">
  <li><a href="#">1r-p.1_1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">1v-p.1_2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">2r-p.1_3</a></li>
</ul>
```

the goal:

```
<ul class="listing">
  <li><a href="#">1r / p. 1_1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">1v / p. 1_2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">2r / p. 1_3</a></li>
</ul>
```

I tried with the following snippet but it doesn't affect anything.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("ul.listing a").text().replace(/-p\./, ' / p. ');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="listing">
  <li><a href="#">1r-p.1_1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">1v-p.1_2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">2r-p.1_3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Have you stepped through the code in a debugger?

Comment: `replace()` does not update the source.  You have to store the changed string back into the place it should go.

Comment: You should be replacing the **text content**, there is no `src` attribute.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I replace text inside a div element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121817/how-do-i-replace-text-inside-a-div-element) or [Jquery: Find Text and replace](//stackoverflow.com/q/8146648)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery: Find Text and replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8146648/jquery-find-text-and-replace)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use the [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) function on the anchors like so:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("ul.listing a").text(function(i,txt) {
    return txt.replace(/-p\./, ' / p. ');
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="listing">
  <li><a href="#">1r-p.1_1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">1v-p.1_2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">2r-p.1_3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Pretty sure down voter meant that with `text()`, and if their will be html inside the anchor, it get stripped out, with `html()` it will be preserved.

Comment: what does the argument "i" in the function
text(function(i,txt) do exactly? It's not used in the function body. can someone elaborate?

Comment: @Trinity76 if you read the docs about the function you'll see that the first argument passed to the function is the index of the element being iterated on. _"function
Type: Function( Integer index, String text ) => String"_