# Constantly loop a javascript array and display results to div?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I have a bunch of testimonials for my site which are currently on a page and am trying to get a div to display each 1 at an interval of 5 seconds, if the array reaches the last value it should start back to beginning of the array again.

Here is what I have so far...

```
var testimonial = new Array();
testimonial[1] = "Rugby";
testimonial[2] = "Baseball";
testimonial[3] = "Cricket";
var length = testimonial.length
var i = 1;
setInterval(function() {
    while (i <= length) {   
        $('#testimonials p').html(testimonial[i]);
        ++i;
        if (i == length) {
            i == 1;
        }
    }
}, 5000);
```

Any help would be great, thanks.

Comment: use [] instead of new Array(). It is better.

Comment: I don't know where you took this code from, but in javascript, indexes start with `0`

Comment: @qwertymk I wrote it and thanks

Comment: Why don't you just put `var i = 1;` inside the anonymous function in `setInterval`? That way it will reset itself. And like qwertymk said, indexes start at 0.

Comment: It is not quite clear what the question is. What is not working?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try

```
var testimonial = ['Rugby', 'Baseball', 'Cricket'];
var numTestimonials = testimonial.length;
var index = 0;

setInterval(function() {
    $('#testimonials p').text(testimonial[index]);        
    index = (index + 1) % numTestimonials;
}, 5000);
```

JavaScript arrays are 0-indexed and have handy array literal syntax. Using the modulus operator (`%`) is an idiomatic way of wrapping a counter back to 0 once it reaches a certain value.

Comment: @divad12 Thanks for this, is the operator you used the same as the modulus one in php? Again thanks, will accept when I can :)

Comment: Can I ask why you changed it from html() to text(), is there any real difference in using one or the other?

Comment: @Colonel I think so -- it returns the remainder of the first operand divided by the second operand. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#.25_(Modulus)

Comment: @Colonel If you just want to display raw strings inside your div, then .text will escape the string for you. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/1910814/392426 and http://api.jquery.com/text/

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
setInterval(function() { 
    $('div').html(test[  (i = (i + 1) % length)  ]) },
5000);
```

Comment: Assuming you start with an index of `0` and not `1`

Answer (score 0):

The function in setInterval is being called every 5 seconds. That means you display the 5 testimonials one after another really quick every 5 seconds instead of displaying them one after the other.

You should do something like:

```
var testimonial = new Array();
testimonial[1] = "Rugby";
testimonial[2] = "Baseball";
testimonial[3] = "Cricket";
var length = testimonial.length
var i = 0; // arrays start with 0

setInterval(function() {
    $('#testimonials p').html(testimonial[i]);
    i++;
    if (i == length) i = 0;
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Many interesting answers, so one more won't hurt. :-)

You can bundle it all up in an immediately called function expression:

```
(function() { 
  var testimonials = ['Rugby', 'Baseball', 'Cricket'];
  var i = 0;
  setInterval(function() {
    $('#testimonials p').text(testimonials[++i % testimonials.length]);
  }, 5000);
}());
```

Comment: The behaviour won't be quite the same because of the pre-increment operator; if you start off `i` at `-1`, then it will display 'Rugby' as the first item. Also, I thought the idiom for an immediately-called function expression is `(function(){ ... })();`, while you have `(function(){...}());` (close parenthesis placement).