# How to show every elements from array repeatedly and stop it on button click

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, loops

I want to make a game which each destination pops up repeatedly. Then, when a user presses the stop button, the random place is selected. I can make the random selection but I don't know how to make every choices in array plays continuously before the user presses the stop button. Below here is what I did so far.

```
var random_place_array = ['Paris', 'Tokyo', 'Bangkok', 'New York'];
var place_length = random_place_array.length;

function start() {
  //once click, clear innerHTML and play the items in array

  for (var i=0; i<=place_length-1; i++) {
    showPlace = "";
    if (i<place_length) {
      showPlace = showPlace + random_place_array[i];
      document.getElementById("place").innerHTML = showPlace;   
    } else {
      i=0;
      start();
    }
   }
  }
```

Now my `document.getElementById("place").innerHTML` shows only the last element in array.

Comment: everytime you are initializing with showPlace=`" "` place it to outside loop

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Constantly loop a javascript array and display results to div?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8252607/constantly-loop-a-javascript-array-and-display-results-to-div)

Comment: @aimee, no it is not, no button.

Comment: I think it is cause the only difference is that when the user presses the stop button you just call `clearInterval(interval);` where `interval = setInterval(....)` to stop the rotations and as pointed out earlier you have to add delay otherwise the changes will not be noticeable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `setInterval` and clear the interval on click. The index could be assigned with the remainder operator and the length of the array.

```js
function change() {
    document.getElementById("out").innerHTML = random_place_array[index++];
    index %= random_place_array.length;
}
  
function stop() {
    clearInterval(intervalID);
}

var random_place_array = ['Paris', 'Tokyo', 'Bangkok', 'New York'],
    intervalID = setInterval(change, 200),
    index = 0;
```

```html
<div id="out"></div><br>
<button onclick="stop();">Stop</button>
```

Comment: Hey, is it possible to make the interval runs after pressing start button without separating function? And what should I do if I want every place to have different colors? Thank you very much.

Comment: for starting on button, you need to put `intervalID = setInterval(change, 200)` into a function. for different colors, you could add span tags to the cities, or use DOM elements and switch visibility.

Answer (score 2):

That could be solved with a [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval):

```
const places = ['Paris', 'Tokyo', 'Bangkok', 'New York'];
let index = 0;

const interval = setInterval(() => {
    document.getElementById('place').innerHTML = places[index];        
    index = (index + 1) % places.length;
}, 100);

const stop = () => clearInterval(interval)
```

And your button:

```
<button onclick="stop();">Select a place</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

You are using the condition:

```
i<=place_length-1;
```

In your for loop and checking the condition:

```
if (i<place_length)
```

The second statement will always be true.

Try removing the condition in for loop.

```
for (var i=0; ; i++)
```