# Make onclick function in HTML to do 2 functions

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick

So this the code I'm doing

```
<a onclick="setStyleSheet('css/blue.css')" href="#">Switch</a>
<a onclick="setStyleSheet('css/red.css')" href="#">Switch</a>
```

On click it'll switch to blue theme. 
But I want to keep the button same.
Instead of using 2 buttons. I just want one Switch button to change to blue, then if I click that button again, it'll change to red. 
Is there anyway to do this?
THanks all in advance!

Comment: This is not a button. It's an anchor. You should use `<button>`

Answer (score 2):

You can set a global flag

```
window.blueTheme = true
function setStyleSheet() {
    var styleSheetToBeSet = window.blueTheme ? "css/red.css" : "css/blue.css"
    window.blueTheme = !window.blueTheme

    // your code here
}
```

Of course, you can change blueTheme to theme and store theme name instead of boolean variable.

And then just call the function without parameter:

```
<a onclick="setStyleSheet()" href="#">Switch</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple, use if loop to compare the argument like

```
function StyleSheet(arg) {
    if (arg == "css/blue.css") {
        var styleSheetToBeSet = "css/red.css";
     }
   else {
       var styleSheetToBeSet = "css/blue.css";
   }
   //set style sheet here with js

}
```

Comment: Where did arg come from? O.o

Comment: <a onclick="setStyleSheet('css/blue.css')" href="#">Switch</a> here "css/blue.css" is the argument for the function setStyleSheet

Comment: So the code would be  <a onclick="setStyleSheet(arg)" href="#">Switch</a> ..?

Comment: Sorry really slow when comes to these stuffs

Comment: no worries, its how you are going to learn, By the way arg is called as argument, it is something value you give to the function, you need to set the link like this <a onclick="setStyleSheet('css/blue.css')" href="#">Switch</a>, the "Arg" is a placeholder for a function argument.If you couldnt understand what i  meant i would advise you to take a programming tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

I would use another helper function and set some condition first.

```
function setElement(){
  var style = document.styleSheets[0]; //set the index
  if(style.href ==='css/blue.css'){
    style.href = 'css/red.css';
  }else if (style.href ==='css/red.css'){
    style.href = 'css/blue.css';
   }else{
   console.log('error');
   }
}

<a onclick="setElement();" href="#">Switch</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest not to use the href="#". This will give uggly urls.
If you use the anchor  better use

```
<a onclick="setStyleSheet('....')" href="javascript:void(0)">Switch</a>
```

Another option is using `event.preventDefault();` in your javascript function.

Answer (score 0):

One approach, that may work (depending upon the complexity of your stylesheets) is to update a CSS custom property to update the properties you wish to change or edit:

```
// defining the colours to be used (the approach taken in these
// code snippets allows for other values to be added to this
// Array to extend the number of colours/values used):
let cssStyles = ['blue', 'red'],

  // defining the function (using Arrow syntax, since
  // we don't need to use the 'this' object within):
  modifyCSS = (styles) => {

    // 'styles': the Array of colours passed into the function.

    // here we find the root-element of the document:
    let root = document.querySelector(':root'),

      // we retrieve the current value of the '--colorValue'
      // CSS property defined in that Node's CSS (if present):
      current = root.style.getPropertyValue('--colorValue'),

      // and, because this property-value is a String, we search
      // the Array of colours to retrieve the index of the current
      // colour:
      index = styles.indexOf(current);

    // here we update the '--colorValue' custom property to the
    // property held in the next index of the Array; or to the
    // value held at the Array's zeroth/first index:
    root.style.setProperty('--colorValue', styles[++index % styles.length]);
  }

// binding the function to the click event on the '#updatecss' button:
document.querySelector('#updatecss').addEventListener('click', (e) => modifyCSS(cssStyles) );
```

```js
let cssStyles = ['blue', 'red'],
  modifyCSS = (event, styles) => {
    let root = document.querySelector(':root'),
      current = root.style.getPropertyValue('--colorValue'),
      index = styles.indexOf(current);
    root.style.setProperty('--colorValue', styles[++index % styles.length]);
  }

document.querySelector('#updatecss').addEventListener('click', (e) =>  modifyCSS(e, cssStyles) );
```

```css
*,
::before,
::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 40vw 40vw;
  width: 80vw;
  margin: auto;
  grid-gap: 4px;
}

.wrapper>div {
  color: var(--colorValue, black);
  border: 2px solid currentColor;
  grid-column: 1/-1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <button id="updatecss">Switch CSS</button>
  <div>element 1</div>
  <div>element 2</div>
  <div>element 3</div>
  <div>element 4</div>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/erojbw9L/1/).

Given that your question requires new stylesheets, and is probably a simplified version of your requirements, it may be more difficult to update CSS custom properties to meet your needs. However, we can use a similar approach with an array of stylesheet names:

```
// CSS stylesheet filenames:
let stylesheets = ['blue.css', 'red.css'],

  // named function, using Arrow syntax as above, to change
  // the stylesheets:
  modifyCSS = (sheets) => {

    // finding the relevant <link> element:
    let link = document.querySelector('.linkedResource'),

      // finding the index of the last '/' character in
      // the href property-value of the <link>; adding 1
      // so that the last slash is included in the 'path'
      // and not the 'file':
      lastSlashIndex = link.href.lastIndexOf('/') + 1,

      // here we find the substring of the href up to,
      // and including, the last '/' character:
      path = link.href.substring(0, lastSlashIndex),

      // finding the filename (based on the assumption
      // that the filename follows the last '/' character):
      file = link.href.slice(lastSlashIndex),

      // finding the index of the current filename in the
      // Array of filenames:
      currentSheetIndex = sheets.indexOf(file);

    // updating the href of the <link> element to be equal
    // to the concatenated value of the path and the
    // filename held at the next, or first, index of the Array:
    link.href = path + sheets[++currentSheetIndex % sheets.length];
  };

document.querySelector('#updatecss').addEventListener('click', () => modifyCSS(stylesheets));
```

```js
let stylesheets = ['blue.css', 'red.css'],
  modifyCSS = (sheets) => {
    let link = document.querySelector('.linkedResource'),
      lastSlashIndex = link.href.lastIndexOf('/') + 1,
      path = link.href.substring(0, lastSlashIndex),
      file = link.href.slice(lastSlashIndex),
      currentSheetIndex = sheets.indexOf(file);
    link.href = path + sheets[++currentSheetIndex % sheets.length];
  };

document.querySelector('#updatecss').addEventListener('click', () => modifyCSS(stylesheets));
```

```css
*,
::before,
::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 40vw 40vw;
  width: 80vw;
  margin: auto;
  grid-gap: 4px;
}

.wrapper>div {
  color: var(--colorValue, black);
  border: 2px solid currentColor;
  grid-column: 1/-1;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.davidrhysthomas.co.uk/linked/blue.css" class="linkedResource" />
<div class="wrapper">
  <button id="updatecss">Switch CSS</button>
  <div>element 1</div>
  <div>element 2</div>
  <div>element 3</div>
  <div>element 4</div>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/erojbw9L/).

References:

- CSS:

  - [CSS Custom Properties (`--*`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*).
  - [CSS Grid Layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout).
- JavaScript:

  - [`Array.prototype.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf).
  - [`CSSStyleDeclaration.getPropertyValue()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/getPropertyValue).
  - [`CSSStyleDeclaration.setProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/setProperty).
  - [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).
  - [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).
  - [JavaScript remainder (`%`) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_()).
  - [`String.prototype.lastIndexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf).
  - [`String.prototype.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice).
  - [`String.prototype.substring()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring).

Bibliography:

- [Constantly loop a javascript array and display results to div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8252607/constantly-loop-a-javascript-array-and-display-results-to-div)