# Difference between text() and html() in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, text

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery: text() vs html()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910794/jquery-text-vs-html)

What's the difference between text and html() in jquery?

Comment: http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Unlike the .html() method, .text() can be used in both XML and HTML
>   documents. The result of the .text() method is a string containing the
>   combined text of all matched elements. (Due to variations in the HTML
>   parsers in different browsers, the text returned may vary in newlines
>   and other white space.)

Source: http://api.jquery.com/text/

This answer was clear from the API docs, though.

If you are ever curious how one or another function works, head to `http://api.jquery.com/[function-name]`. If the answer is not in the main text, look through comments. If you haven't found your answer yet, spend at least 2 minutes using Google. If you haven't found your answer yet, ask in stackoverflow.