# jQuery Selector to find content of td

Tags: jquery

My HTML structure looks something like below:

```
<div id="mainDiv">
<table></table>
<table></table>
<table>
<tr>
<td id="first">FirstCell</td><td id="second">SecondCell</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td><td></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Now I would like the find the content of second td based on the value of first td.

I have tried following but didn't seem to work.

```
$("#mainDiv tr td:contains('first')").each(function(){
                var secondCell = $(this).find('#second').value();
            });
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: change `var secondCell = $(this).find('#second').value();` to `var secondCell = $(this).next().text();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your html structure you can achieve what you want like this

```
$("#mainDiv tr td:contains('First')").each(function(){
                var secondCell = $(this).next().text();
                console.log(secondCell);
            });​
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/uBQuy/)

Like @Blender said `.value()` is not a function, use [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) instead.

Answer (score 1):

value is not a valid method.

You should use one of these as per requirement.

```
.html()  // for html content.
.text()  // for text content.
.val()   // for value attribute. Like value of input element.
```

Comment: I wouldn't list `.val()`. That function is only for input elements and will just confuse people.

Comment: I have mentioned that in the comment.

Answer (score 0):

`.value()` isn't a function. You're probably looking for `.text()`.

Looking at your structure, I see that you are looking for `#second` relative to `#first`. Are there multiple elements that have `id="second"`? If so, you're going to run into a *lot* of trouble with jQuery, as the `id` attribute is meant to be unique to a single element. You should be using `class` instead of `id` if the property is used to identify more than one element.

Answer (score 0):

as you are using `each`, instead of an id, class names should be used, try this:

```
$("#mainDiv tr td:contains('first')").each(function(){
    var secondCell = $(this).siblings('.second').text();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

when you say find, do you mean using regex? or by relationship of/to the first.

If by relationship, then this will work

```
$("#mainDiv tr td:contains('first')").each(function(){
            var secondCell = $(this).next().html();
        });
```

.text() is sometimes better than .html() depending on what you are doing. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910794/jquery-text-vs-html) for working example and more info.

If by Regex, you will have to provide what it is you are looking for in the first `<td>`.