# Get row number of current element in table structure

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I have a HTML structure like below:

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td><a booking="1" class="event_start"></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td><a booking="1" class="booking_end"></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I need jQuery for `booking_end` click event which tells which row it is in, and which td `booking_start` is in, `booking_start` and `booking_end` are linked by an attribute `booking`.

So on click in above case I need output `2,3`. where `2` is the `tr` number in which `booking_end` exists and `3` is the td number in which its `booking_start` exists.

Comment: Do you mean `event_start` instead of `booking_start`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11026738/jquery-selector-to-find-content-of-td             Try this

Comment: Like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/j8e6cnh0/2/)?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: Yes event_start

Comment: @Dense: http://ttcube.co.in/booking/make_booking.php

Comment: @Gladiator9: its not of help

Answer (score 1):

You can get the element index with its siblings.  Use the [`index`](https://api.jquery.com/index/) function that returns the zero-based index.

You will need to use the function on the row itself, e.g.

```
$('a').click(function()
{
     var self = $(this),
         row = self.closest('tr'),
         rowIndex = row.index();

     // do something with rowIndex
});
```