# jQuery contains append find text string and more code

Tags: jquery, string, find, append

need a little help finishing this code;

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
     var username = $('div.subtitle span').text();
     var $Head = $('div.main-content #field_id4 dt span'); 
     var $body = $('div.main-content #field_id5 dt span');
     var $contBody = $('div.main-content #field_id6 dt span');
     var $borders = $('div.main-content #field_id7 dt span');
$Head.filter(':contains("Black")')
     .closest('#profile-advanced-layout')
      .prepend('<div id="blackbg">'+ username +'Profile</div>');
$body.filter(':contains("Black")')
      .closest('#profile-advanced-layout')
        .css({'background':'#000'});
$contBody.filter(':contains("Black")')
      .find('.main-content')
       .css({'background':'#000'});
$borders.filter(':contains("Black")')
     .find('main-content')
       .css({'border':'2px solid #000'});
 });
```

My biggest problem here, since this is only maybe third time using variables. Though if you look at the variable `$username`, what I am trying to do is search inside the div `.subtitle` span and get the text string that is within that span, then copy it or whatever,

then where is says `$Head.filter`, I want it to be "+username+Profile", is that correct for the variable to be in placed like that. And how would i go about finding that text string correctly?

Comment: to get text inside the element you have to use the .text() method, and not just select the DOM element

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to do this:

```
.prepend('<div id="blackbg">' + $username.text() + 'Profile</div>');
```

or if you have the text in a separate variable called `username`:

```
.prepend('<div id="blackbg">' + username + 'Profile</div>');
```

Comment: ok so thats how I would get that. Now how would I write that in the variable format?

var username = .find('.subtitle span').text();

then in the head var I would do +$username+? or still + username.text() +

Comment: @user1760670 once you have text in the string, you can't use `.text()` anymore.  It's just a string.  If you do `var username = .find('.subtitle span').text();` then you want to use `+ username +`.  Note that your code is wrong because you don't close the string.  Look at mine.

Comment: sorry close the string?? you mean like 'code' + username + 'code' ?

Comment: @user1760670 no; you never assign anything to `username`

Comment: I thought I did by doing var $username = $('div.subtitle span').text();  sorry this is new to me so

Comment: Think of `$` like any other letter.  There is hardly a difference between a variable named `ausername` and `$username`.  It is not functional.  Change `$username =` to `username =`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20453/discussion-between-explosion-pills-and-user1760670)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$username.html(); 

$username.text();
```

Also the `$` is not need in a variable name you could do

```
var username = $('div.subtitle span').html();
```

See [What is the difference between jQuery: text() and html() ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910794/jquery-text-vs-html)

Comment: `$` is not needed, but I tend to name variables that contain jQuery objects as such

Comment: so the var username is correct then. So when I type the var in the $Head.filter blah blah blah +$username.text();+ or what