# ajax,jquery in .jsp page

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I m new to jquery nd ajax kindly help me in this code as dis code is not working it is showing complete html code instead of text(hiiiii)
**A.html**

```
<html>
<head>

<title>Insert title here</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#btn").click(function(){
    $.post("hello.jsp",function(data,status){
      $("#mydiv").text(data);
    });
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h2>AJAX</h2>
<button type="button" id="btn">Request data</button>
<div id="mydiv"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**hello.jsp**

```
<html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
    </head>
    <body>
   <%
    int i=0;
    int j=++i;
    out.println(" hiiiiii" +(j));
    %>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**output**
ajax
a button
jsp page's code

Comment: in hello.jsp, just add the jsp part.

Answer (score 0):

just change this

```
 $("#mydiv").text(data);
```

to

```
 $("#mydiv").html(data);
```

and also check this [What is the difference between jQuery: text() and html() ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910794/what-is-the-difference-between-jquery-text-and-html)

Answer (score 0):

You are inserting the data with `$("#mydiv").text(data);`. The [manual for that function](http://api.jquery.com/text/) says:

We need to be aware that this method escapes the string provided as necessary so that it will render correctly in HTML. To do so, it calls the DOM method `.createTextNode()`, **does not interpret the string as HTML**.

That page also mentions [the `html()` method](http://api.jquery.com/html/), which is what you want to insert HTML into a document.

```
$("#mydiv").text(html);
```