# How do I find an element before a clicked on link?

Tags: jquery

If I have code like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <span class="pID">12342123</span>
  <a href="#" class="but">click here</a>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <span class="pID">98765432</span>
  <a href="#" class="but">click here</a>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <span class="pID">2342342</span>
  <a href="#" class="but">click here</a>
</div>
```

How do I make it so if the link is clicked on, go to the pID and grab the # within the a's own container?

```
$('.but').on('click',function(){
   var pID = $(this).parent('pID').text(); ?
});
```

For your information, I don't have any control of putting the PID in the anchor.

Comment: You can also use `.prev()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.but').on('click',function(){
   var pID = $(this).siblings('.pID').html();
});
```

Some considerations on whether to use .text() or .html():

[What is the difference between jQuery: text() and html() ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910794/what-is-the-difference-between-jquery-text-and-html)

If using as a callable function called as onClick="doThis(this);":

```
function doThis(el) {
    var pID = $(el).siblings('.pID').html();
}
```

Comment: I'm a dope... put the onclick in the wrong element. Thanks Mate!

Answer (score 1):

You were close.  The element is a sibling, not a parent.

```
$(this).siblings('.pID').text();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$('.but').on('click',function(){
  var pID = this.parentElement.children[0].textContent
});
```

assumes the html structure does not change (e.g. children[0] is always the span you are looking for