# How to find particular label value inside div tag using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, innerhtml

I need to read the value of particular label inside the div tag using jQuery. Below is the HTML structure.

```
<div id="myDiv">
<label id="greenLabel">Hello</label>
<label id="redLabel">There you go!</label>
</div>
```

Can anyone help me to find the inner text of "redLabel" ?

Comment: Maybe `$('#redLabel').html()` ?

Answer (score 4):

Try [**#** id-selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)

```
$('#redLabel').text();
```

or

```
$('#redLabel').html();
```

---

`$('#redLabel')` -->refers to element with `id` `redLabel`

`$('#redLabel').text();` --> get text of element with `id` `redLabel`

`$('#redLabel').text('value');` --> set text of element with `id` `redLabel`

---

[.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

[.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

---

`ID` must be unique. Use `classes` for multiple items or refer to a group

Read [Two HTML elements with same id attribute: How bad is it really?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/127178/two-html-elements-with-same-id-attribute-how-bad-is-it-really)

Comment: writing directly "$('#redLabel').text();" reads all the labels in the page. I want to read it from particular div tag.

Comment: @DhavalPanchal that read only label for ID redLabel and if ID are uniques then you get only one value.

Comment: Yes - ID is unique. I have ASP.Net label within DIV and set ClientIDMode="static". So, It renders HTML as mentioned in Question.

Comment: @DhavalPanchal if id is unique it must select only one label .

Comment: ID is unique within that div tag. But in page there are too many labels with the same name.

Comment: @DhavalPanchal label id's also must be unique or you can use class instead for all labels .

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 $("#myDiv #redLabel").text();
  //go to div then label
 // or can try if in label there is no element
     $("#myDiv #redLabel").html();
```

you can also use `$("#redLabel")` at the place of `$("#myDiv #redLabel")`

see also [What is the difference between jQuery: text() and html() ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910794/what-is-the-difference-between-jquery-text-and-html)