# Jquery show HTML Tags not a results of this tag?

Tags: jquery, tags

Why after this script:

```
$("<span />", { text: this.value+' <br /><br />', "class":"view" }).insertAfter(this);
```

I see text `<br /><br />`. I want to see results not a HTML tags.
Plz any help

Comment: use html instead of text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use html

```
$("<span />", { html: this.value+' <br /><br />', "class":"view" }).insertAfter(this);
              //^
```

Read [What is the difference between jQuery: text() and html() ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910794/what-is-the-difference-between-jquery-text-and-html)

[.html()](https://api.jquery.com/html/)

Answer (score 0):

Replace your value to this:

```
html: this.value + ' <br /><br />', "class": "view"
```

#### Why?

Because you are updating the `text` which is the visible value of the element.

Using `html` you will write the value next to it, as the HTML content. And the `<br />` will be used as a line break.