# html() method versus text() method

Tags: jquery

Some or more people use html() method to get element's text like the `<p>text</p>` and to get this `$('p').html()` or `$('p').text()`.

And obviously I know there is huge difference between html method and text method. But I would like to know more on this context, what's the better to use?

Some one might say text method is better than html method, please explain why?

Comment: There is no concept of one being "better" than the other, only of one being better suited to solving *that particular problem* than the other. If you need the HTML, you obviously use `.html()`, if you want the HTML to be removed, you obviously use `.text()`. If you can guarantee they'll return exactly the same content regardless, it doesn't matter either way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are preferences for people to use when and why to use html and/or text method but I would like to inform you the html() method is faster than text() method:

> html method is only a wrap to innerHTML, but with text method jQuery add an "entity filter", and this filter expand time.

- .text() can be used in both XML and HTML documents.
- .html() is only for html documents.

[See more info here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910794/what-is-the-difference-between-jquery-text-and-html)

<s>So, which one you want to use?</s>

Answer (score 0):

When you need html *formatting/style* while text is being rendered then you should use `html()` and when you need just text then go for `text()`

Answer (score 0):

These methods are derived from textcontent / innerhtml..

```
$('#yourid').text() = document.getElementsByID('yourid')[0].textContent);
hello <span>
```

You should use `.text()` if you want to get the HTML without escaped characters..

```
$('#yourid').html() = document.getElementsByID('yourid')[0].innerHTML
hello &lt;span&gt;
```

If you wanted to set HTML or get raw escaped HTML you should use `.html()`;

Answer (score 0):

As per jQuery says,
The result of the `.text()` method is a string containing the combined text of all matched elements.

***Due to variations in the HTML parsers in different browsers,

the text returned may vary in newlines and other white space.***

The `.text()` method cannot be used on
form inputs or scripts.
As of jQuery 1.4, the `.text()` method returns the value of text and `CDATA` nodes as well as element nodes.***

Answer (score 0):

`.text()` adds the given expression as a text, `.html()` adds it to the dom as an html expression

here is an example;

```
var str = '<strong>HELLO</strong>'
$("#addHere").text(str);
```

=> you will see the actual string `<strong>HELLO</strong>` in `#addHere`

```
var str = '<strong>HELLO</strong>'
$("#addHere").html(str);
```

=> you will see a bold HELLO in `#addHere`

Answer (score 0):

jQuery provides 2 functions text() and html() and when to use text() function and when to use html() function is quite confusing as both the functions are different and serve different purpose.

.html() - This jQuery function gets/sets the HTML of any element.
.text()- This jQuery function gets/sets the text (innertext) of any element.

[What is the difference between jQuery: text() and html() ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910794/what-is-the-difference-between-jquery-text-and-html)