# Line break in jquery/ javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

nowadays i am upto java script, jquery etc. i am facing little problem.

i am writing a text message inside CASE block , it's a long string when displayed:

```
Record has been saved successfully Note: If head already exists for the concerned department than your head selection would not have been saved.
```

but i want it like this:

```
Record has been saved successfully 
Note: If head already exists for selected department 
than your head selected would not have been saved.

function ShowMsg() {
        var MessageStatus = $("#HiddenFieldSetMessage").val();
        switch (MessageStatus) {
            case 'SavedButHeadMightExist':
                $("#Msg").text("Record has been saved successfully Note: If head already exists for the concerned department than your head selection would not have been saved");
                $("#ModalHeader").text("Success");
                break;
            case 'NotSaved':
                $("#Msg").text("Record not inserted");
                $("#ModalHeader").text("Error");
                break;
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use newlines, but those aren't really shown, what you really want is probably just break tags

```
$("#Msg").html("Record has been saved successfully<br />" +
               "Note: If head already exists for the concerned department<br />" +
               "than your head selection would not have been saved");
```

Note that you have to change the method from `text()` to `html()`

Answer (score 1):

you need to use `<br/>` for line break. and use `html` instead of `text`

text: it is used for text only no html is allowed
html: it allow html tags also

You can find difference between these two here

1. [What is the difference between jQuery: text() and html() ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910794/what-is-the-difference-between-jquery-text-and-html)

Answer (score 0):

Change .text to .html

```
$('#Msg').html('line1<br>line2');
```

OR

```
var escaped = $('<div>').text(stringDisplay).text();
$('#Msg').html(escaped.replace(/\n/g, '<br />'));
```