# Hot to prevent .text to escape the html tags on the browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The following code apparently escapes the HTML tags and prints

`<p>Full Membership - 1 Year:<span>$25</span></p>`

on the Browser instead of

`Full Membership - 1 Year:$25`

```
$(".ms_total").text("<p>Full Membership - 1 Year:<span>$25</span></p>");
```

How do I prevent that?

Comment: use `.html` instead of `.text`

Comment: Example from SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910794/what-is-the-difference-between-jquery-text-and-html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try [.html](http://api.jquery.com/html/) :-

```
$(".ms_total").html("<p>Full Membership - 1 Year:<span>$25</span></p>");
```

As documented in official site :-

> Get the HTML contents of the first element in the set of matched
>   elements or set the HTML contents of every matched element.

Answer (score 1):

Use `.html` insted of `.text`. Because .text displays the contents which is in quotes

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nrsantharam/fajoe670/)