# How to display html with javascript

Tags: javascript

I take data with post method now I need to display html into page here is code:

```
  function(data,status){
         $("#ul1").text(data);


    });
```

This will show `<li></li>` tags inside ul like text not like html how can I show data as html?

Comment: See it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910794/what-is-the-difference-between-jquery-text-and-html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use [`html`](http://api.jquery.com/html/):

```
$("#ul1").html(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [jQuery html("") method](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html-htmlString)

For example:

```
$("#ul1").html(data);
```