# input type text field value not returning exact text

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net

I am developing an application in ASP.NET using C#. I am doing all the client side operations through JQuery. In my page I have a html label control and html input type text control. I have to show the input type text value to the label. For that purpose I have written following code:
HTML:

```
<input type='text' id='txtName'/>
<input type='button' id='btnDisplay' value='Display'/>
<p id='lblName'></p>
```

JQuery Code:

```
$("#btnDisplay").click(function(){
$("#lblName").html($("#txtName").val());
```

});

It is working fine for single space between two words. But if write "abc     xyz" then it is showing only "abc xyz". I have to display exact same text of input type. It should show "abc     xyz".

How can I do that? Please help. 
http://jsfiddle.net/shubhadeepchat/w19o8pot/

Comment: its a 2 step process, check out my answer
You need to do both the steps

Comment: This is not necessarly a two-steps process. It's only need to replace white space with correct HTML entities, as I shown in my answer :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZX4x9/1/)

```
#lblName {
    white-space: pre;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using

```
<pre id='lblName'></pre>
```

Or

```
<pre><p id='lblName'></p><pre>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/w19o8pot/2/)

You could also take a look at this solution with [css](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
p {
    white-space: pre;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>
This       is some text. This is some text. This is some text.
</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

As A. Rama said the HTML is guilty for that. Anyway you could mislead HTML replacing the simple white spaces with proper HTML entities (i.e `&nbsp;`). In below example, the regular expression (the first parameter of `replace`) will search for every occurances of white space and replace it with entity (the second parameter).

This resolve as **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/49wq7t18/)** demonstrate only editing JS and leaving HTML as it was:

```
$("#btnDisplay").click(function(){
    $("#lblName").html($("#txtName").val().replace(/\s/g,"&nbsp;"));
});
```

The use of `text()` doesn't work as I tested in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v5mn3ah5/) (cause you can't update `p` tag with `text()` function).

And after all, even if `text()` would work you can't insert HTML tag as input since this tag will not be rendered.

Comment: True that!. Though can you please explain more about the regular expression sort of thing within the parenthesis of .replace().

Answer (score 0):

The val function is working properly.

But in HTML, multiple white spaces (that is, spaces, tabs, returns, etc...) are almost always showed as a single one.

Use

```
$("#btnDisplay").click(function(){    
  alert($("#txtName").val());
});
```

and you'll see all the white spaces where they should be.

Comment: Forgot a closing parentheses but it works correctly otherwise. http://jsfiddle.net/w19o8pot/4/

Comment: But certainly we do not want an alert pop-up box!

Comment: That's another question altogether. OP asked about the fact that jQuery and input were not returning correct text. They were, it was the way he choose to show them that was improper. I showed this.

Answer (score 0):

Use [text](http://api.jquery.com/text/) property instead of html:-

```
$("#lblName").text($("#txtName").val());
```

With CSS (took from @Mangesh) answer:-

```
#lblName {
    white-space: pre;
}
```

Comment: @marianoc84 - Okay was not able to access the fiddle at that time, so couldn't understand OP's question properly, But in my opinion `text` should be used instead of `html`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a two step process

STEP 1:

Do not use `.html`

`.html` will append the value as html into the label
So try using `.text()` which will append exact value

So you should use

```
$("#lblName").text($("#txtName").val());
```

Step 2:

Use `<pre>` tag

```
<input type='text' id='txtName'/>
<input type='button' id='btnDisplay' value='Display'/>
<pre><p id='lblName'></p></pre>
```

Here is updated fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/w19o8pot/3/

If you dont do step 1, then your functionality will fail for the following input

```
<b> hi </b>
```

This question explains the difference with more examples

[What is the difference between jQuery: text() and html() ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910794/what-is-the-difference-between-jquery-text-and-html)

Answer (score 0):

Use JS function as per below, it will preserve all spaces:

```
$("#btnDisplay").click(function(){    $("#lblName").html(encodeURIComponent($("#txtName").val()).replace(/%20/g,'&nbsp;'));
});
```