# How to keep CSS style If I change the html content dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I dynamically change the HTML content. But when I change the content, all the CSS styling is removed. How can I keep the CSS style when I change the content dynamically?

```
<div id="sample">
    <a href="#" onClick="call()">Change it </a>
    <p id="para"> I am paragraph </p>
</div>
```

```css
p {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

```js
function call(){    
    $("#para").replaceWith('oops css gone');
}
```

Here is the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rajagopalx/6sbvtpp6/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue is because you're replacing the entire `p` element with a textNode. Instead, just change the text of the initial `p` element by using the `text()` method:

```
function call(){    
    $("#para").text('oops css gone');
}
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/6sbvtpp6/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
function call(){    
    $("#para").replaceWith( '<p id="para">oops css gone</p>');
```

}

Don't forget to replace your tags as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you replacing the element with a new one you could store the classnames and replying them to the new element.

```
.highlight {
    background-color: yellow;
}
----------------------------------------------
var replacedElement = $("<div />");
var storedClass = $("#para").attr("class");

replacedElement.text("yeah css still there");   
replacedElement.attr("class",storedClass);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6sbvtpp6/2/

Answer (score 0):

you can also use .html() function of jquery

```
function call(){    
    $("#para").html( 'oops css gone');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

.replaceWith replaces the entire element. There are many ways to go about it. Simplest of all is, either go for :

```
 function call(){    
        $("#para").text( 'oops css gone');
    }  

    or

    function call(){    
        $("#para").html( 'oops css gone');
    }
```

There is this SO [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910794/what-is-the-difference-between-jquery-text-and-html) for an understanding on the difference between `.text()` and `.html()`