# I want insert <br> Before Some Specific Text in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I want to insert the break tag before  the **Estimated Time of Arrival**  Can Anybody Help

```
<span class="avl">Excludes: Northern Territory, QLD Far North, QLD Regional, WA Regional, WA Remote Estimated Time of Arrival: 3-8 Business Days,</span>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get the text of that particular span and then add `<br>` tag next to the  occurring string as shown.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var string = $(".avl").text();
     var usingBreak = string.replace("Estimated Time of Arrival", "<br/>Estimated Time of Arrival");
   $(".avl").html(usingBreak );
});
```

Comment: .html() will do the job... [What is the difference between jQuery: text() and html()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910794/what-is-the-difference-between-jquery-text-and-html)

Answer (score 2):

Use `replace` function.

Here's the code for that (say you have the content of the span in a variable called `str`):

```
var withBreak = str.replace("Estimated Time of Arrival", "<br/>Estimated Time of Arrival");
```

If you don't have the text stored in a variable, you could use [Document.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) and then use `.text()` to get the content of your span. Than after you changed the value you can just set the Text to your edited string.

Comment: No Its Not possible to Add the <br/> Infront of the Text because it's coming from the DB

Comment: Than please add that important detail to your question, and make it more clear. Is it always the same text where you want to break the text?

Comment: Yes, its the Same text always I want to add the Break