# Special character behaves as escaped in an updated DOM element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an HTML element that I wish to modify via Javascript. It contains a special character `&copy;`.

If I leave the HTML alone, I get what I expect. In its original state, it is

```
<li id="cp">&copy; MyCompany</li>
```

and then the line renders as "© MyCompany".

I want to auto-update that to display a range of years as the calendar changes, so I added some Javascript to the document's onload() function.

```
var today = new Date();
var cptext = "&copy; 2011-" + today.getFullYear().toString() + " MyCompany";
$('#cp').text(cptext);
```

But then, when the page loads, the `&copy;` is left as its original text, so the user sees the original `$copy; 2011-2015 MyCompany` instead of what I want, which is "© 2011-2015 MyCompany". The automatic date range code works fine, but the normal symbol replacement goes away.

How can I get the symbol to be updated as it is in the static HTML when I use jQuery/Javascript to modify the DOM element?

I do not have the option of recoding the entire HTML page as PHP.

Comment: Use the `.html()` method instead of the `.text()` method. A related question: [What is the difference between jQuery: text() and html() ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910794/what-is-the-difference-between-jquery-text-and-html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var today = new Date();
var cptext = "&copy; 2011-" + today.getFullYear().toString() + " MyCompany";
$('#cp').html(cptext);
```

you need to use `$.html(htmlstring)` instead.

http://jsfiddle.net/uffghLz6/

http://api.jquery.com/text/#entry-examples

text() strips any of the html and returns only the text. It's like using element.innerHTML vs element.innerText

Comment: That fixed it. Thanks.