# Change text with function and include bullet images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to figure out something without results. I have a Simple `<img>` used as button, and if I click on it, the text from other `<h3>` elements should change. That part is working, but I'm also trying to include on the new text an image as a Bullet element, but it's not working, it's rendering as text too. Here's my actual code:

HTML:

```
 <img id="button1" src="images/info.png"/>
 <h3 class="text1"> Here's some temporal text </h3>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
 $( "#button1").click(function() {
 $(".text1").text('This will be the new text also including a bullet <img src="images/bullet.png" style="margin-right:10px;"/> And here continues the text, but seems to be that the bullet is not being rendered:( only as text');
 });
```

Could you help me to find a solution?

Answer (score 3):

Use  [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) instead of `.text()` as `.text()` will only set `textContent` of the element, it will not insert provided argument as `DOM Element`

```js
 $("#button1").click(function() {
   $(".text1").html('This will be the new text also including a bullet <img src="images/bullet.png" style="margin-right:10px;"/> And here continues the text, but seems to be that the bullet is not being rendered:( only as text');
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="button1" src="images/info.png" />
<h3 class="text1"> Here's some temporal text </h3>
```

Comment: For further reference: see [What is the difference between jQuery: text() and html()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910794/what-is-the-difference-between-jquery-text-and-html) and [documentation for jQuery's html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/).

Comment: thanks @RayonDabre it works fine! you're the best, so that's the answer to my problem, use .html instead of .text