# retrieve an array from a php encoded json and append it to a div body

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, json

I've been looking for hours and I can't find an answer to this.

I'm sending this array

```
$dailyHours = ['8:00','8:30','9:00','9:30','10:00','10:30','11:00','11:30','12:00','12:30','13:00','13:30','14:00','14:30'
,'15:00','15:30','16:00','16:30','17:00','17:30','18:00','18:30','19:00','19:30'];
```

endoded in a json using this code:

```
$list = array('hours' => $dailyHours);

$c = json_encode($list);

echo $c;
```

I want to display it on an html div. For that I'm using this code:

```
success: function(msg,string,jqXHR){

                    $("#result").html(msg.hours);
                }
```

This doesn't work, and the error I'm getting is:

Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.

I'm guessing this doesn't work because I either can't encode it like that or I can't append it like that. Is there any way of doing this? Thanks

edit: 
result of console.log(msg.hours)

{"hours":["8:00","8:30","9:00","9:30","10:00","10:30","11:00","11:30","12:00","12:30","13:00","13:30","14:00","14:30","15:00","15:30","16:00","16:30","17:00","17:30","18:00","18:30","19:00","19:30"]}

Comment: Have you tried a simple consol.log(JSON.stringify(msg)) to confirm you are getting back from the json service what you expect?

Comment: What does `msg.hours` contain?

Comment: msg.hours contains the array $dailyHours, or at least it should. I'll try running the console log to see what I'm getting. edit: I'm getting the array, so it has to be something wrong with how I'm trying to display it.

Comment: Try doing `$("#result").text(msg.hours);`...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between jQuery: text() and html() ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910794/what-is-the-difference-between-jquery-text-and-html)

Comment: @brso05 When I run that, I have this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: @A.Draug I don't see `length` anywhere in your code...

Comment: @A.Draug did you log `msg.hours`? What are the contents of `msg.hours` in the console?

Comment: Neither do I, I have no idea why I'm getting this error. If I try to display a single string, it works fine, when I try the array, I get the error. Adding the content of msg.hours to main post

Comment: @A.Draug Maybe try `$("#result").text("" + msg.hours.toString());`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`msg.hours` is an array and jQuery’s `.html()` method accepts a string as a parameter.

You should convert the array to string first by toString() method.

Try this:

```
       $("#result").html(msg.hours.toString());
```