# convert .html value to string in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

HTML:

```
<td id="myid">something</td>
```

JavaScript:

```
var test = $("#myid").html();
console.log(test);
if(test == "something"){
alert("Great!");
}
```

my problem here is that in the console the word something appears but when it is on the condition they do not match, maybe because the .html value retrieved is not a string. So I want to know how do I convert it to string?

Comment: What is html of the div ?

Comment: @MairajAhmad let me post it

Comment: Your code works, make sure that `myid` is unique

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **[`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/)** method to get text content and **[`String#trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim)** ( or **[`jQuery.trim()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim)**) to remove the white space from both end of string.

```js
var test = $("#myid").text().trim();
console.log(test);
if (test == "something") {
  alert("Great!");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="myid">something</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

For understanding the difference Refer : [What is the difference between jQuery: text() and html() ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910794/what-is-the-difference-between-jquery-text-and-html)

```js
console.log(
  $("#myid").text(),
  $("#myid").html()
)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="myid"><span>something</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks! but may I know why did .text and not .html? for future reference.

Comment: @hungrykoala : in your case both will be work since there is no html element inside

Comment: @hungrykoala put the text in span and you will see the difference

Comment: @guradio : that would be easy to understand :)

Comment: Refer following [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/7sLt9skc/1/) for reference.