# How to write dynamic text between div tags?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am typing with the div on the login screen. I want this article to be dynamic. That's why I am using ajax jQuery to pull data. I want it to be written in the div. How do you do that?

```
<div class ="bas">Write here(title)</div>
```

```js
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: MY,
    success: function (msg, result, status, xhr) {
        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(msg);
        title = obj[0].Write;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use either `text()` or `html()` to set the content of the required `div` element. Try this:

```
<div class="bas">Write here(title)</div>
```

```js
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: MY,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(msg) {
        $('.bas').text(msg[0].Write);
    }
});
```

Note that by using `dataType: 'json'` jQuery will deserialise the response for you, so you don't need to call `JSON.parse` manually.

Comment: No problem, glad to help

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) or [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) depends on what object contains.
 If containing data includes html tags such as `<strong>` or .. use `html()` but if it's plain text use `text()` instead.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url:MY,
    success: function (msg, result, status, xhr) {
        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(msg);
        title= obj[0].Write;
        $('.bas').html(title); // this line
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.text()` function

```
<div class ="bas">Write here(title)</div>
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url:MY,
    success: function (msg, result, status, xhr) {
        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(msg);
        title= obj[0].Write;
        $(".bas").text(title);
    }
});
```

Comment: Well, there is no need to use `.html()` unless OP specifies what she/he wants to write... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910794/what-is-the-difference-between-jquery-text-and-html

Comment: Do not use comments to thank everyone, mark the right answer as accepted and upvote every answer that helped you with the problem. Meaning no offense, but "thank you" is off-topic ;-)

Comment: @elementzero33  Hi, ı have reached your question limiT. Would you please give me a positive votes? I have questions to ask

Answer (score 0):

Use [hanlderbars.js](http://handlebarsjs.com/)    or    `<div class ="bas">Write here<span class="title"></span></div>`

Answer (score 0):

if only remote read text file

```
<div class="bas">Write here (title)</div>

jQuery.get(myURL, /*ifMyParams,*/ function(data){
  jQuery('.bas').text(data);
})
```