# Cannot implement line breaks inside .text() - \n not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to have the following text with break lines in my .js file:

```
button = 0;

var cardTextDefault = function(textInProzent){
    $("#button").text('text part I.\n is:'+percent+'%\n\n text part two');
}
```

This var is afterwards called when clicking the button:

```
cardTextDefault(button.value);
```

Do you have any clue why \n is not breaking my line?

Comment: Add <br> tag instead

Comment: You need to use html(). Text is surprisingly just text. See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910794/what-is-the-difference-between-jquery-text-and-html

Comment: use <br> like `'text part I.'<br>' is:'+percent+'%'<br> 'text part two'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not how line breaks work in HTML (/jQuery)

Use this instead:

```
button = 0;

var cardTextDefault = function(textInProzent){
    $("#button").html('text part I.<br /> is:'+percent+'%<br /><br /> text part two');
}
```

Note that I replaced `.text` with `.html`. `.text` would've escaped the HTML in there.

Comment: Thanks, this fixed the problem!