# Is there any way to hide a character which is inside an html tag?

Tags: jquery, html, css

The span tag with `class="WooZone-free-shipping"` has an `&` character just inside it. I cannot remove it from the code for some reason but I have to hide it on this page. 
I tried to do it with the following jQuery:

```
jQuery('.WooZone-free-shipping').html(jQuery('.WooZone-free-shipping').html().replace("&",""));
```

and with this css:

```
span.WooZone-free-shipping:nth-child(1) {
    display: none;
}
```

But these two methods did not work.

[image]

Comment: Afaik, you cannot apply css to individual characters within a text node.  It's all or nothing.

Comment: You might want to try text-indent with a negative value. Use with caution, and if it's a link, don't do it as it could negatively affect your site in terms of SEO (it's frowned at by Google and other search engines).

Comment: @LuisSerrano it's not a link.

Answer (score 1):

`html()` will convert `&` to `amp`. You need to use `text` while replacing

```js
console.log("TEXT - "+jQuery('.WooZone-free-shipping').text());
console.log("HTML - "+jQuery('.WooZone-free-shipping').html());
jQuery('.WooZone-free-shipping').html(jQuery('.WooZone-free-shipping').text().replace("&",""));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="WooZone-free-shipping">ABC&amp;D</div>
```

Comment: bhai I want to know a little more about the first two lines.

Comment: Which one the one where data is getting logged in console??

Comment: Yes. A little explanation would do.

Comment: @Rahul check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910794/what-is-the-difference-between-jquery-text-and-html. It will clear your doubts and do accept and upvote the answer :)