# Looping DOM element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get the titles and loop them to get the innerHTML.

My code is not working. Why? Please, explain because this happens very often and I dont know the solution

```js
function createInputsForWebAppRemotes() {
  var titles = $('.collapseTitle');
  for (var title in titles) {
    console.log(title.html());
    if (title.html().indexOf("(CSR)" || "(ADMIN)")) {
      $('#remoteWebAppDiv').append('<input class="form-control" name="remoteWebAppUrl" type="url"/>');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Don't use a `for..in` loop on a jQuery object. Use the `each()` method. Also the syntax for `indexOf()` is incorrect. To help you we need to see the HTML and have a more complete description of the problem. Any errors in the console? What does/does not happen?

Comment: `<a class="collapseTitle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse-sql_test0">sql_test (SQL) </a>`

Comment: I changed to `$.each(titles, function (index, title)` and I get Uncaught TypeError: title.html is not a function

Comment: Please add any additional information to the question, not as comments.

Comment: 1) Please edit the question to add detail. Code in comments is hard to read 2) Use the `each()` method, not `$.each()`: http://api.jquery.com/each/

Comment: Please create a fiddle, so we can fork and edit to suite your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The for...in statement iterates over the enumerable properties of an object

<sup>https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in</sup>

In this case jQuery element (the output of `$` function) is not `enumerable properties` but a jQuery object. So the right way is to use [`$().each`](https://api.jquery.com/each/)

> Iterate over a jQuery object, executing a function for each matched element.

Suppose your html is partial similar to the code below:

```js
function createInputsForWebAppRemotes() {
  var titles = $('.collapseTitle');
  titles.each(function() {
    var title = $(this).html();
    console.log(title);
    if (title.indexOf("(CSR)") > -1 || title.indexOf("(ADMIN)") > -1) {
      $('#remoteWebAppDiv').append('<input class="form-control" name="remoteWebAppUrl" type="url"/>');
    }
  });
}

createInputsForWebAppRemotes();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="collapseTitle">Title 1</div>
<div class="collapseTitle">(CSR)</div>
<div class="collapseTitle">Title 3</div>
<div class="collapseTitle">(ADMIN)</div>

<div id="remoteWebAppDiv"></div>
```

Also as [@Mihai T](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6441124/mihai-t) mention, you have problems with the usage of `indexOf`:

1. You need to check of the index is greater than -1 because this is the output of this function for string which no included in another string.
2. The `||` need to be between sentences but not as argument in `indexOf` function.

Comment: i guess that `if` should append an input only if the title contains those strings in the `if` condition. Your answer adds 4 inputs even if you don't have those strings in the title. Plus i guess you should use `text()` instead of `html()` when looking for ...well...text :)

Comment: You are right. I didn't write code for copy / paste, just to explain the point. OP need to understand it and implement it in his code. Also, `html()` vs `text()` the first is winning - https://stackoverflow.com/a/18418270/863110 but thanks for your comment :)