# Django - Update div as plain text after I create a post using ajax

Tags: ajax, django, django-views

My project has a Post model. My home page has list of all post and post_create form. I create post using ajax view. Intention was to create a new post and update the home page without page refresh. Here is the code, 
views.py,

```
 def post_create_ajax(request):
   if request.is_ajax():
      if request.method == 'POST':
        title = request.POST.get('the_post')
        author = request.user
        post = Post(title=title, author=author)
        print(title)
        post.save()
        return JsonResponse({'title': title})
```

The script,

```
$('#postform').submit(function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
   console.log('Working');
   create_post();
});

function create_post(){
   console.log('Create Post is working');
   var posttitle = $('#id_title').val();
   $.ajax({
      url: '/ajaxcreate/',
      type: "POST",
      data: {
          the_post: posttitle,
          csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}',
      },
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data){
          $('#id_title').val('');
          console.log(data.title);
          $('#post_title_content').html(data.title);
       },
       error:function(){
          console.log('Error Occoured');
          alert('Error');
       },
   })
}
```

This part works fine. The page new post is getting added without refresh.

Here is a problem. After I submit a post, the new title that getting added are not safe.

e.g. if I add `<b> This is a title </b>`, The new div is added with **This is a title** and only returns to plain text `<b> This is a title </b>` after I refresh the page.

So my question is how to change my script so that it will update div as plain text?

Images:

New post is added, but not in plain text,

[image: The text is added but not in plain text]

After I refresh it shows as plain text,

[image: After I refresh it shows in plain text]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `.text(data.title)` instead of `.html(data.title)`. There is more information on this other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910794/what-is-the-difference-between-jquery-text-and-html).

Answer (score 3):

You should use .text instead of .html on this line

```
$('#post_title_content').html(data.title);
```

jQuery.html() treats the string as HTML while jQuery.text() treats the content as text