# How to stop appearing <br/> tag while trying to echo "<br />" in php?

Tags: php

Not working echo `"<br/>";` in php  showing the result with `<br/>`,there is no line break. Can any tell me why it's happening?

## script.js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    
    jQuery('.form1').on('submit',function(){
        
        $.ajax({
            'url' : 'process.php',
            'success' : function(result){
                jQuery('.info').text(result);
            },
            'data': {
                'nam' : 'Ratul',
                'address' : 'Dhaka',
            },
            'type' : 'POST'
        });
        return false;
    });
    
});
```

## process.php

```
<?php

$name = $_POST['nam'];
$address = $_POST['address'];


echo "Name:".$name;
echo "<br />";
echo "Address:".$address;
```

Comment: What **exactly** are you looking for?

Comment: Use `html(result)` instead `text(result)`

Comment: `html()` vs `text()` https://stackoverflow.com/q/1910794/12731030

Answer (score 2):

In your Javascript you're using `jQuery('.info').text(result);`

This takes "result" and prints it directly as text. What you most likely want to do is `jQuery('.info').html(result);` This will print it properly with html tags rendering.

Answer (score 1):

Use `html(result)` instead `text(result)`

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery('.form1').on('submit',function(){

        $.ajax({
            'url' : 'process.php',
            'success' : function(result){
                jQuery('.info').html(result);
            },
            'data': {
                'nam' : 'Ratul',
                'address' : 'Dhaka',
            },
            'type' : 'POST'
        });
        return false;
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this? `"\r\n"` instead of using `<br>`

```
echo "Name:".$name."\r\n";
echo "Address:".$address."\r\n";
```