# Do I need to escape string if I use .html() in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, escaping

I have the following line in my js file.

`$( '#currency' ).html( '$' );`

Do I still need to escape the "$" string? Anyway, what is the safest way to output a dollar sign?

Comment: "*what is the safest way to output a dollar sign?*" `.text( '$' )` [What is the difference between jQuery: text() and html() ?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1910794)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As its says in JQuery docs:

> Unlike the .html() method, .text() can be used in both XML and HTML
> documents. The result of the .text() method is a string containing the
> combined text of all matched elements. (Due to variations in the HTML
> parsers in different browsers, the text returned may vary in newlines
> and other white space.)
>
> The .text() method cannot be used on form inputs or scripts. To set or
> get the text value of input or textarea elements, use the .val()
> method. To get the value of a script element, use the .html() method.

so if u just want to output a dollar sign, .text() would be safe as its value would be parsed as string...