# How to replace the contents of a existing div with another div contents?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html, replace

I have a pop up window.On click of a next button in a pop up window,the contents of current `div` must be replaced with another `div` contents.I want to repeat this action repeatedly on click of same next button with another `divs`. How to achieve this?

Comment: Did you try anything yet?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7139208/change-content-of-div-jquery

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
var a = $('#div1').html();
var b = $('#div2').html(a);
```

Of course it is using Jquery.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
function fun()
  {
   document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML=    document.getElementById("div2").innerHTML;
   }
```

call this function onclick event of button.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery .html() method to get content from div and then add this content to destination div
Checkout sample on jsFiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/btPb6/

```
function replaceContent(source, destination){
    $('#'+destination).html($('#'+source).html());
}
```