# Ajax change wrapper content

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dynamic-data

I'm trying to develop my skills with Ajax
I want to change my wrapper content with a different pages wrapper content without having to refresh the page.

I'm using:

```
$(function () {
    $("#page2btn").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'page2.asp',
            data: { id: $(this).attr('id') },
            success: function (data) {
                $('#Wrapper').html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<div id="Wrapper">
    <div id="menu">
        <a class="navbutton" onclick="MakeRequest1()">Home</a> <span class="navbutton">|</span>
        <a class="navbutton" id="Page2btn">Page2</a> <span class="navbutton">|</span>
        <a class="navbutton" onclick="MakeRequest3()">Page3</a>
    </div>
    <h1>Test1</h1>
</div>
```

and another page called page2.asp
with a different wrapper content saying Test2 
But my wrapper wont change when I click the button.
any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Where is the `#Wrapper` element? Have you checked the console to ensure that the request is successful?

Comment: Just didn't indent it :p

Comment: Are `MakeRequest1()` and `MakeRequest2()` defined somewhere ?

Comment: Hello, put an alert(data) or console.log(data) to make sure that your request is ok. Or replace `$('#Wrapper').html(data);` with: `$('#Wrapper').empty(); $('#Wrapper').append(data);`

Comment: Do you want <h1>Test1</h1> to be populated with the new content that is "Test2", right ?

Comment: On page 2 the content is "<h1>Test2</h1> I want this to appear on page1 where it says <h1>Test1</h1> without refreshing the page

Answer (score 1):

Try to simplify it to determine if this is a problem with your front-end or back-end code...

Try this and see of it works any better..

```
$('#Wrapper').load('page2.asp?id='+$(this).attr('id'));
```

Comment: Well, that's the most very basic way to load content into a div. Are you getting an error? Have you ensured you are capturing the ID correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(function () {
    $("#page2btn").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'page2.asp',
            data: { id: $(this).attr('id') },
            success: function (data) {
                $('#dynamic_content_div').html(data);//data = <h1>Test 2</h1>
            }
        });
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="Wrapper">
    <div id="menu">
        <a class="navbutton" onclick="MakeRequest1()">Home</a> <span class="navbutton">|</span>
        <a class="navbutton" id="Page2btn">Page2</a> <span class="navbutton">|</span>
        <a class="navbutton" onclick="MakeRequest3()">Page3</a>
    </div>
    <div id="dynamic_content_div">
    <h1>Test1</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is case sensitive. You are using lowercase in case of assigning the event -

```
$(function () {
    $("#page2btn").click(function () { //lowercase P
        ...
    });
});
```

but using uppercase for html id

```
        ...
        <a class="navbutton" id="Page2btn">Page2</a> <span class="navbutton">|</span> //upper case P
        ...
```

so, it never finds the item to bind to, thus nothing happens when you click. Either change js to -

```
$("#Page2btn").click(function ()
```

or change html to -

```
<a class="navbutton" id="page2btn">Page2</a> <span class="navbutton">|</span>
```

Other than this, I don't see the error.

Answer (score 1):

Try jQuery **replaceWith** method, like this:

```
$(function () {
   $("#page2btn").click(function () {
      $.ajax({
          url: 'page2.asp',
          data: { id: $(this).attr('id') },
          success: function (data) {
              $("#Wrapper").replaceWith(data);  //try with double qoutes
          }
      });
   });
});
```

*The link below maybe helpful:

[Change content of div using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7139208/change-content-of-div-jquery)