# Setting innerHTML with PHP?

Tags: php, html, button, innerhtml

So basically I have this program that sets a header (id="infoHeader") at the top of the page to some text retrieved from another site. I need this however to change when a button is pressed. As you can see it currently uses a PHP script to fetch the text from a given URL but I need to fetch from a different URL when a button is pressed. So basically

Button1 press -> infoHeader = Site 1 text

Button2 press -> infoHeader = Site 2 text

Is there a way to use a button to change the innerHTML of [id="infoHeader"] so that it runs the PHP script to get the text.
It is kind of difficult for me to explain, if you need I can try and give more info.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>KSA Flight Tracker</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="KSAStyle.css"/>    
</head>

<body>
<div id=page>

    <div id=leftPanel>
        <p id=missionsHeader>Active Missions</p>
        <p><?php include("getList.php")?></P>
    </div>

    <div id=info>
        <p id=infoHeader><?php include("getData.php"); getTitle("http://www.blade-edge.com/images/KSA/Flights/craft.asp?r=true&db=dunai"); ?></p>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: you'd probably have to use javascript for this one

Comment: But I need to run this PHP script to get the text so how would I run that with javascript?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use **JavaScript** + **AJAX**. JavaScript  is needed to change the content of the `div` after the page is loaded/rendered and AJAX for loading a PHP file without the need to refresh the web page.

I recommend you to use **jQuery** and it's `ajax` function.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>KSA Flight Tracker</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="KSAStyle.css"/>    

    <!-- include jQuery -->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>

    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() { // wait for the DOM to finish loading

        // button1
        $("#someID").click(function() { // element with id "someID" (your button)
          $.ajax({
            url: "getData.php", // the content of the page which you want to load
            cache: false
          }).done(function(dataFromServer) {
            $("#infoHeader").html(dataFromServer); // set the data from the server (getData.php) as the content of the element with the id "infoHeader"
          });
        }):

        // button2
        // the same as above for the other button

      });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="page">

      <div id="leftPanel">
        <p id="missionsHeader">Active Missions</p>
        <p> <?php include("getList.php"); ?> </p>
      </div>

      <div id="info">
        <p id="infoHeader"> <?php include("getData.php"); getTitle("http://www.blade-edge.com/images/KSA/Flights/craft.asp?r=true&db=dunai"); ?> </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

For your problem:

1. [Change content of div - jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7139208/)
2. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Here are some good resources for JavaScript, jQuery and AJAX:

1. **JavaScript**: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript
2. **jQuery**: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery
3. **jQuery**: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/
4. **jQuery**: http://www.codecademy.com/en/tracks/jquery
5. **jQuery + AJAX**: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_intro.asp

Comment: I just did a quick google search on all this and I don't really get how to do what I want. (I only started HTML,CSS & PHP yesterday - I am learning it pretty quickly but I am stuck). So how would I use this to change the text with 'ajax'?

Comment: Ok so I tried reading through [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7139219/2758663) but I still don't get what I am supposed to do. Where do I put it? What needs to be changed so it will work with my program? etc. Like I said - I am new and until 30 minutes ago had never even heard of AJAX or jQuery.

Comment: I tried reading them but it may as well be in Japanese - I just can't make any sense out of it...

Comment: Updated my answer with an example.

Comment: Thanks this helps a lot but could I get some clarification on what to change for it to work by using these words.
  
ID of click detecting element: "someID"  |
File with function: "getData.php" |
PHP Funciton: "getTitle(URL)" |
Text to change: "infoHeader" |