# Changing div content when clicking buttons

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make some sort of gallery on my website. There are 3 buttons, and underneath some text and picture are placed. When I click the button, I want that the content changes (to the content from button #2 etc.). How can I achieve that?

```html
<ul>
  <a href="">
    <li>Btn1</li>
  </a>
  <a href="">
    <li>Btn2</li>
  </a>
  <a href="">
    <li>Btn3</li>
  </a>
</ul>

<div class="list-first"">
  <p class="list-first list-first-mobile">some text from first btn</p>
  <img src="imgs/stock1.jpeg" alt="jpg from first btn" class="list-first-img">
</div>
```

Comment: you can use jquery to achieve this. First of explain clearly that what you want to replace and where.

Comment: please see this link first : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7139208/change-content-of-div-jquery

Comment: As said above, you can use jQuery. Also note that the `<div class="list-first"">` of your HTML is invalid and should be `<div class="list-first">`

Comment: Please don't use anchor tags for buttons. Use buttons for buttons. `<button>`'s are for doing things. `<a>`'s are for going places.

Comment: thanks guys! I will check that link in a moment. I want to replace all content from div called list-first (text and img).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this ,hope it helps

```js
document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach((el, i) => {
  el.addEventListener("click", () => {
    document.querySelectorAll('p').forEach(ed => ed.style.display = "none")
    el.nextElementSibling.style.display = "block"
  })
})
```

```html
<style>

.loc-caption:before {
  content: attr(title);
  display: block;
}

ul {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  width: 25%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

li img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

 
</style>

<ul>
  <li class="loc-caption"><button>ClickME</button>
    <p style="display:none" class="list-first list-first-mobile ">
      <img src="https://chainimage.com/images/related-pictures-natural-sceneries-beautiful-wallpapers.jpg" alt="jpg from first btn " class="list-first-img "> some text from first btn
    </p>
  </li>
  <li class="loc-caption"><button>ClickME2</button>
    <p style="display:none" class="list-first list-first-mobile ">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRwXvWYU5tYrokWILC7lgjmCYqYGvActZnt9q8AcPs4dR7hMTBR" alt="jpg from second btn " class="list-first-img "> some text from second btn
    </p>
  </li>
  <li class="loc-caption"><button>ClickME3</button>
    <p style="display:none" class="list-first list-first-mobile ">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTzzP-CJnW3xuNeqqMcNLzK_IFPCywsEKifAWlajEzWcdALIDLI" alt="jpg from third btn " class="list-first-img "> some text from third btn
    </p>
  </li>

</ul>
```

Comment: It's not what I wanted to achieve. [screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/IRbRjuJ) <- I want that the content (this content which I marked with white border) changes when you press the buttons. Like a some kind of 'gallery'. When you press first, it changes back to previous content etc. I'm really struggling with this and have no idea

Comment: content is chnaging here when you press the buttons in my example @miron

Comment: Yeah, but not changing to previous, eg. from third to first. I want that every button has its own content (photo+text)

Comment: @miron Could you explain more ,I can change my answer accordingly

Comment: [That's what I made with Chrome Inspector and want to achieve on live website](https://imgur.com/a/hgVa35w) 
and thank you in advance!

Comment: I have edited my answer,you can add your css like you want @miron

Comment: yes, that's what Ive been looking for. Thank you, really! :D