# Remove child element

Tags: jquery

How can I remove the *foo* `label` as well as the `div` child element and the `br`'s?

```
<label>qux</label>
<label>foo</label><div id="block">text</div><br /><br />
<label>bar</label>
```

My current makeshift method:

```
$('label:contains("foo")').next().remove();
$('label:contains("foo")').remove();
```

How can I improve upon this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just `did on what html you posted` here.

Try this:

```
 $('label:contains("foo")').remove(); // <-----------label contains foo removed
 $('#block').remove(); //<---------------------------div with id 'block' removed
 $('label:contains(qux)').nextAll('br').remove(); //<--finally all the br next to first label removed
```

[**checkout on fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/w25eA/)

and even a better one with `.nextUntil()`:

```
$('label:contains("qux")').nextUntil($('label:contains(bar)'),$('label, br')).remove();
```

[**fiddle for `.nextUntil()`**](http://jsfiddle.net/w25eA/1/)

Answer (score 14):

Very simple:

$(element).children().remove();

So easy...

Answer (score 1):

Use .html() method and set it to null.

Check [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309452/how-to-replace-innerhtml-of-a-div-using-jquery) for reference

Answer (score 1):

```
if($("label").text()=='foo'){
   $(this).next('div').remove();
   $(this).closest('br').remove(); 

   // I've used next and closest methods to remove..you can try with others..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a great way to improve the removal of the foo `<label>`. You could improve the removal of the `div`, syntactically, by using

```
$('label:contains("foo") + div').remove();
```

CSS adjacent sibling selector.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('label').each(function(){
    var self = $(this);
    if(self.text() == 'foo'){
          self.next('div').remove();
          self.parent().find('br').remove(); //else use two times next() to remove two br tags.
          self.remove();
    }
});
```

please mention the parent element inside the `.parent()`,
something like this:

```
parent('div')  //if you have a parent container as div.
```