# Javascript : Inject inline code to a html tag

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, inline, inject

I would like to add my Google Analytics tracking event code inline to my **input** html tag :

```
<input class="addtobag">
```

to have something

```
<input class="addtobag" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Videos', 'Play', 'Baby\'s First Birthday']);">
```

I'm asking this as I don't have access to the file that contains the  tag so I'm unable to make the change manually so I'm looking for a javascript code that I will put in the **head** so when that page load, the tracking event code would be injected automatically.

I want the call to be by my **input class** and not by **id**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you want to do it inline?

```
document.getElementById('ctl00_mainContentPlaceHolder_lvLookProducts_ctrl0_buyArea3493_btnAddToCart').onclick = function () {
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Videos', 'Play', 'Baby\'s First Birthday']);
};
```

---

To do it by class name, you'll need to do a little more logic:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('AddToBag'),
    i = inputs.length;

while(i--) {
    inputs[i].onclick = function () {
        _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Videos', 'Play', 'Baby\'s First Birthday']);
    }; 
}
```

Fetching by class name returns a list, so you'll have to loop through to apply the handler.

Comment: I'm open to any any better alternative you may show me. Thanks

Comment: Ok can I use the class "AddToBag" for the getElementById instead of using ct100_mainCont.... ??

Comment: because the website is generating an ID dynamically for each <input>, using the class(addtobag) would be better as it is static

Comment: Thanks a million! I'm going to test this out and will update you.

Comment: Hi again, I need your help with a very similar question, instead of onclick I would like to set it up using onBlur and onChange.

onBlur if the value is not blank inject : _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/vpv/FirstName.aspx']);   or onChange(a slect field) inject ....

Comment: works the same way. What have you tried? Also, you should ask a new question rather than piggybacking on an existing one.

Comment: I tried to do it using your code just by changing "click" by "blur" or "change" but it didn't work, I have created a new question here  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15258968/javascript-inject-inline-code-to-a-html-tag)

Answer (score -1):

jQuery is your friend.

[How to replace innerHTML of a div using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309452/how-to-replace-innerhtml-of-a-div-using-jquery)

```
$("#regTitle").html("Hello World");
```

**EDIT**

Guess I didn't read this one, but still same principle.

```
$(".addtobag").click(_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Videos', 'Play', 'Baby\'s First Birthday']));
```

http://api.jquery.com/click/