# How to re write innerHTML in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following in my js.

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
this[i].innerHTML = thehtmlval;
}
```

I want to write the same in jQuery.

I did some search and saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309452/how-to-replace-innerhtml-of-a-div-using-jquery) but dont know how to apply it in this case. Can someone please help.

Comment: $("#elementid").html(thehtmlval);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume `this` in your code is a `NodeList`:

```
$(this).each(function() {
  $(this).html(thehtmlval);
});
```

Or just: `$(this).html(thehtmlval);` because jQuery already did the loop for you inside.

Comment: The `.each` is superfluous since you are setting the same innerHTML on every element in the set.

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
$(this).html(thehtmlval);
```

if multiple then you can use jquery `$.each()`

Comment: welcom.. glad it helped... happy coding

Answer (score 1):

First we should know what **this** is.

For example if this is just a div, you could use the next code:

```
${'#myDivId'}.html(thehtmlval); 
or
${this}.html(thehtmlval);
```

If you are trying to add a text, you can use the next one:

```
${'#myDivId'}.text(thehtmlval); 
or
${this}.text(thehtmlval);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    $(this[i]).html(thehtmlval);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try  `html()` which ovverides previous html in side the `selector`

```
$(selector).each(function() {
  $(selector).html(htmlval);   //ovverides previous html in side the selector  
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/html/

Answer (score -2):

instead of using innerHTML or HTML() use text().

Comment: The OP has asked to rewrite html and `text()` would write html elements as plain text.