# Unable to add dynamic generated html to a specific place

Tags: jquery

On click of the Button , i am trying to add the dynamically generated html  to a specific position .

I am trying to add at **Add it to here** present inside HTML section .
This is my complete program

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on("click", "#moreFieldsBtn", function() {
   var orderconfirmhtml = $('<h4>Complete your order</h4>');
   $(this).parent().next('.Test-details').after(orderconfirmhtml);
});
 </script>
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="collapsible">
    <div class="prd-items-detials">
        <ul>
            <li class="head">
                <form>
                    <label class="testtt" for="checkbox-mini-0">Test Item</label>
                </form>
            </li>
            <li class="prd-items-qt">
                <div class="col"> <span class="prd-sm-img"><img id="imagesd" type="img" height="40" width="40"  src="' + image + '"/> 
                    </span> 
                </div>
                <div class="col"> <i class="minus" id_attr="59"> </i>
 <i class="qt_class" id_attr="59">1</i>  <i class="plus" id_attr="59"> </i> 
                </div>
                <div class="col"> <a href="#" id_attr="59" class="btn btn-sm">Topping</a> 
                </div>
                <div style="display: none;" class="price" id_attr="59">50</div>
                <div class="col total" id_attr="59">50</div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="59" class="Test-details">// Add it to here</div>
</div>
<input type="button" id="moreFieldsBtn" value="Add Data To Specific Place" />
</body>
```

But nothing is being added there , could anybody please tell me how to resolve this ??

Comment: Here's a good place to start: http://api.jquery.com/html/

Comment: where is .Test-details?

Comment: Thats a div  class   <div id="59" class="Test-details"> , present inside HTML Section .

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to replace innerHTML of a div using jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309452/how-to-replace-innerhtml-of-a-div-using-jquery)

Comment: I think `$(this).parent().find('.Test-details').after(orderconfirmhtml);` will do. Problem is that `$(this).parent()` refers to body tag. Just guess what `$(this).parent().next('.Test-details')` will point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your javascript code should be something like this

```
$(document).on("click", "#moreFieldsBtn", function() { 
   var orderconfirmhtml = '<h4>Complete your order111</h4>';
   $(this).parent().find('.Test-details').append(orderconfirmhtml);
});
```

or

```
$(document).on("click", "#moreFieldsBtn", function() { 
   var orderconfirmhtml = '<h4>Complete your order</h4>';
   $(this).parent().find('.Test-details').html(orderconfirmhtml);
});
```

refer this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/WGQv6/1/ or http://jsfiddle.net/WGQv6/2/

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#moreFieldsBtn').click(function () {
            var orderconfirmhtml = $('<h4>Complete your order</h4>');
            $('.Test-details').html(orderconfirmhtml);
        });
    });
</script>
```

For a function inside $(document).ready() method, it can run java code before page loaded, and uses jquery selector to find html element. And Jquery can bind event actions.