# Why does this line Javascript work, but the other doesn't?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I'm trying to update the contents of a div #letters. I tried assigning the element to a variable and updating its content using innerHTML, but it doesn't work.

```
  var $characterArray = $('#letters'); // The letters div
  $characterArray.innerHTML = "whatever";
```

While this works:

```
  document.getElementById("letters").innerHTML = "whatever";
```

Can you please tell me why?

Comment: `innerHTML` is a property of DOM element, whereas `$characterArray` is a jQuery object. You have to use `.html()` method instead of `innerHTML`

Comment: `var $characterArray = $('#letters')[0];`

Comment: `$characterArray[0].innerHTML = "whatever";` would work.

Answer (score 5):

Because you're muddling jQuery with native JS. The jQuery object has no such property `innerHTML` - that is a native property.

The equivalent in jQuery is the method `html()`

```
$('something').html('my html');
```

Answer (score 2):

The first code snippet uses the jQuery library (not vanilla JS) which has different method names for setting the inner HTML content of an element. Correct usage of jQuery is:

```
var $characterArray = $('#letters'); // The letters div
$characterArray.html('whatever');
```

Answer (score 2):

The first line is not vanilla Javascript. It requires the JavaScript Framework called [jQuery](https://jquery.com).

If you like to rely on jQuery and you [included it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/547482/318765) in your page then you can use [`html()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1309454/318765):

```
$("#letters").html("whatever");
```

P.S. I assumed that you did not know about jQuery because the `jQuery`-tag was [added later](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/29734322/revisions) through @DarrenSweeney.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to code against the native HTML element you can use indexes to get to it:

```
var $characterArray = $('#letters')[0]; // The letters div
$characterArray.innerHTML = "whatever";
```