# A loop within a loop - Javascript

Tags: javascript, loops

I have a problem with a loop inside a loop.

By selecting the number and clicking the "Generate boxes" button it generates boxes with numbers from 1 to 49.
If you click the first time everything works fine.
But if you add more boxes it once again adds those 49 numbers to the already existing boxes. That's the problem. I only want to generate new boxes with numbers from 1 to 49.

This is the code:

```
function kasterl() {
    $(".plunder").click(function() {
        var wert = $( "#wieviel option:selected").text();       
        MyInt = parseInt(wert);     
        createKaesten(MyInt);   
    });
}   

function createKaesten(zahl) {
    var gesamt = $(".kasten").length+1;
    var numberOf = $(".kasten").length; 

    for(var i=1; i<=zahl; i++) {
        $(".rahmen").append("<div class='kasten nr"+ gesamt +"'><ul></ul></div>");
    }           

    for(var n=1; n<=49; n++) {
        $(".kasten ul").append("<li class='nummer'>" + n + "</li>");
    }       
}
```

And here you can test it: [link for testing](http://www.matuk.de/zufall.html)

Comment: Your loop is not inside a loop.

Comment: That's what you get with that horrid indentation scheme (tnx @endless for screwing up the point I was trying to make :P)

Comment: Yes I know. But I have to do it like this. Or how could I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have found, `$(".kasten ul").append(...)` will append to *all* elements that matched the `".kasten ul"` selector.

You said you had a problem with a "loop within a loop", but your current code doesn't in fact nest the loops. Following is a solution that actually does nest the loops:

```js
function createKaesten(zahl) {
  var gesamt = $(".kasten").length + 1;
  var numberOf = $(".kasten").length;
  var newUL;

  for (var i = 1; i <= zahl; i++) {
    newUL = $("<ul></ul>");
    for (var n = 1; n <= 5; n++) {                       
      newUL.append("<li class='nummer'>" + n + "</li>");
    }
    $("<div class='kasten nr" + gesamt + "'></div>").append(newUL).appendTo(".rahmen");
  }
}

$("button").click(function() {
  createKaesten(3);
});
```

```css
li { display: inline-block; padding: 0 10px; }
.kasten { border: thin black solid; margin: 2px; padding: 0px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Test</button>
<div class="rahmen"></div>
```

The outer loop creates a new, empty UL, then the inner loop appends the new LI items to that UL, then we create a DIV, append the new UL to it, then append the DIV to the `.rahmen"` container.

(Note that for demo purposes each click of the button only adds 3 x 5 items, rather than something x 49 items, and I've styled the LIs to go across the page horizontally so that it's easier to see what's happening. Click "Run code snippet" to try it out.)

Comment: Amazing! This really seems to work. Thank you! 
(And sorry, I've had a variant of a loop inside a loop before. But then I tried and tried and tried .. so this version I posted here was not a loop inside a loop.)

Answer (score 0):

Note in the code that you use the function `$().append()`

Appending does just that - it appends new content to the end of existing content. Append will be executed every time you click generate.

Edit: I added a [codepen](http://codepen.io/rodneywells01/pen/GjgRvP) to illustrate this. Hit each button multiple times to see the difference.

Comment: you have to do append in jquery, don't you?
document.write doesn't work.

Comment: You can overwrite the contents of a div without simply adding to the end of the div. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309452/how-to-replace-innerhtml-of-a-div-using-jquery for additional information.