# jQuery outputting an html div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to output a div inside another div  with jQuery

first principal div :

```
<div id ="username_error"></div>
```

and this one will be inside it :

```
 <div class="alert alert-primary" role="alert">
    This is a primary alert—check it out!
 </div>
```

I tried

```
$("#username_error").html('<div class="alert alert-primary" role="alert">
  This is a primary alert—check it out!
    </div>
');
```

but it doesn't work , is there an alternative method 
thanks in advance

Comment: You need to actually provide the HTML to insert as an argument to the `.html()` call...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace innerHTML of a div using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309452/how-to-replace-innerhtml-of-a-div-using-jquery)

Comment: i did that but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add this to your JQ:

```js
$("#username_error").html('<div class="alert alert-primary" role="alert">This is a primary alert—check it out!</div>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id ="username_error">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var content = '<div class="alert alert-primary" role="alert">This is a primary alert—check it out</div>';

$("#username_error").html(content);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use append function

```js
$("#username_error").append('<div class="alert alert-primary" role="alert">This is a primary alert—check it out!</div>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id ="username_error">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('<div class="alert alert-primary" role="alert">This is a primary alert—check it out!</div>').appendTo("#username_error");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id ="username_error">

</div>
```