# How to replace innerHTML of a span using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

How could I achieve the following:

```
document.regTitle.innerHTML = 'hello';
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you have and what research have you done? This is easy to research in most any basic jQuery tutorial and in the api docs as well as in web search engine. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Have you tried anything so far? StackOverflow expects you to [**try to solve your own problem first**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). Please attempt something, then update your question to show a **specific** problem you're having in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stackoverflow is not a free code conversion service and issue is easily researched

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/html/ boom done

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace innerHTML of a div using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309452/how-to-replace-innerhtml-of-a-div-using-jquery)

Answer (score 4):

You should add this

```js
$(function(){
    $('button').click(function(){
        $('span.regTitle').text('Span Text Replaced');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span class="regTitle">Sample Content</span>
<br/><br/>
<button>Replace Span</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function(){
$('#regTitle').html('this is a test');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="regTitle"></div>
```

Here's a snippet for jQuery innerhtml.