# Display List Item all details when clicked on specific list Item using razor pages and View Component

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

[image]

I have been trying for a long time to do display the details of the list item when we click on the list item but I am only able to display a static contact by this code :

```
    <div id="contactdetail">
        @await Component.InvokeAsync("ContactDetails", new { id = 1})
    </div>
```

In MVC we can call the view by using Jquery similar to this :

```
$("#listitem").click(function () {
        $("#contactdetail").load('/ContactDetails/Invoke')
    })
```

but here using only razor pages and Entity Core framework, how am I suppose to do this and in this, we also need to pass the Id as that will be responsible for getting the respective contact and then load the view.

My ContactDetailViewComponent.cs :

```html
public class ContactDetailsViewComponent : ViewComponent
    {
        private readonly IContactDetails contactDetails;

        public Contact Contact { get; private set; }

        public ContactDetailsViewComponent(IContactDetails contactDetail)
        {
            this.contactDetails = contactDetail;
        }

        public IViewComponentResult Invoke(int id)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Called {0}", id);
            var contact = contactDetails.GetContact(id);
            return View("Default", contact);
        }
    }
}
```

Index.chtml which contains both the list and details :

```html
<!-- Contacts Heading -->
<h4 class="p-3 px-4 font-weight-bolder">Contacts</h4>

<!-- Parent container for the the below list and displaying addresses-->
<div class="container-fluid py-3 px-4  h-100">
    <div class="row">
        <!-- Column which contains the list of all the contacts present currently -->
        <div class="col-md-4 ">
            <ul class="list-group contact-list-cards">
                @foreach (var contact in Model.Contacts)
                {
                    <li class="list-group-item py-0 px-3 position-relative"
                       >
                        <a class="stretched-link contact-name  curson_pointer text-decoration-none name-heading m-0"
                           href="#"
                           id="listItem"
                           onclick="loadDetails(@contact.Id)" >@contact.Name </a>
                        <p class=" text-secondary m-0 mx-2 ">@contact.Email</p>
                        <p class=" text-secondary m-0 mx-2 mb-2">+91 @contact.MobileNumber</p>
                    </li>
                }
            </ul>
        </div>

        <!-- Column which will display the informaation when clicked on the specific list item of contact -->
        <div id="contactdetail">
            @await Component.InvokeAsync("ContactDetails", new { id = currentId })
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Partial View method used :

Load details method :

```
function loadDetails(id)
    {
            console.log(id);
            $("#contactdetail").load("/Contacts/Index/OnPostContactPartial?id="+id,
            function (res, status, xhr) {
            if (status == "error") {
             console.log(status);
            alert("An error occurred while loading the results.");
            }
            });
            console.log($("#contactdetail"));
     }
```

Index.chtml file where I am calling this load Detials :

```html
<!-- Parent container for the the below list and displaying addresses-->
<div class="container-fluid py-3 px-1  h-100">
    <div class="row">
        <!-- Column which contains the list of all the contacts present currently -->
        <div class="col-4 ">
            <ul class="list-group contact-list-cards">
                @foreach (var contact in Model.Contacts)
                {
                    <li class="list-group-item py-0 px-3 position-relative">
                        <a class="stretched-link contact-name  curson_pointer text-decoration-none name-heading m-0"
                           href="#"
                           id="listItem"
                           onclick="loadDetails(@contact.Id)" >@contact.Name </a>
                        <p class=" text-secondary m-0 mx-2 ">@contact.Email</p>
                        <p class=" text-secondary m-0 mx-2 mb-2">+91 @contact.MobileNumber</p>
                    </li>
                }
            </ul>
        </div>

        <!-- Column which will display the informaation when clicked on the specific list item of contact -->
        <div id="contactdetail" class="ml-5">
            <partial name="_contactDetail" model="@Model.Contacts.ElementAtOrDefault(0)" />
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Contact Partial method in Index.chtml.cs :

```
        public IActionResult OnPostContactPartial(int id)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("func called {0}", id);
        Contact contact = contactDetails.GetContact(id);
        return Partial("_contactDetail", contact);
    }
```

If I don't pass any Id and just pass a specific contact (ex - contact having id 3) then it is working fine i.e when I click on any contact ITem then it displays, but when I pass the Id field then I am getting a 404 error.

Here's my folder directory :
[image]

Please guide me How can I do this.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `InvokeAsync` method instead of `Invoke` in the ContactDetailsViewComponent.cs file

Comment: bro, but we also have to change the data which we are passing to view component, how can we do that ??

Comment: sounds like a job for javascript to me, call a api endpoint and return the json you need

Comment: @WalterVehoeven sir, please elaborate your answer, I can't get any idead, do you mean to use ajax and jquery for this, In MVC I think we can do this using load method from ajax, but I have no idea regarding razor pages and we also need to pass the id as parameter,

Comment: rather than do a post bak and get the whole page again use jquery and get the data and update the web page using the response have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309452/how-to-replace-innerhtml-of-a-div-using-jquery

Answer (score 1):

You can use ajax in razor page the same as that in mvc.

First, create a new razor page, you can call it `ContactDetails.cs`:

```
public class ContactDetailsModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly IContactDetails contactDetails;

    public ContactDetailsModel(IContactDetails _contactDetails)
    {
        contactDetails = _contactDetails;
    }

    public Contact Contact { get; set; }

    public void OnGet(int id)
    {
        var contact = contactDetails.GetContact(id);
        Contact = contact;
    }
}
```

And add Contact detail information in the Page `ContactDetails.cs.cshtml`(for simple, I just show the four fields)

```
@page
@model RazorTest.Pages.ContactDetailsModel
@{
    Layout = null;
}

@Model.Contact.Id
@Model.Contact.Name
@Model.Contact.Email
@Model.Contact.MobileNumber
```

Then, in `Index.chtml`, use ajax in the click function of the anchor:

```
<script>
    function loadDetails(contactId) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'get',
            url: 'ContactDetails?id='+contactId,
            success: function (result) {
                $("#contactdetail").html(result);
            }
        })
    }
</script>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: thank you much sir, I will try to do it,
But Sir, actually I am trying to do it by partial view, I have called the load details method similar to yours one, but I am getting 404 error, Please can you see the code, I have posted it in the question .

Comment: @VR7, Route in Razor Page is different from that in MVC, change it like below: `'/Contacts/Index?handler=ContactPartial&id='+id`, and the handler should be `OnGetContactPartial` since you send a get request.

Comment: Thanks very much, sir, I have been trying to solve this problem for 2 days, yes I was also thinking a little that why is it post request though earlier I was sending data, and that one URL caused so much problem, I searched many places but mostly I found solutions for MVC instead of razor pages, Thanks very much, sir,
Sir, can you please share some resources link from where I can learn and practice ajax and jquery since I am new to asp.net core.

Comment: @VR7, first is the offical doc of [razor page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio) and the [tutorials](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/) from this site is also very good. For ajax and jquery question, you can just search it based on specific sitiuation, on stackoverflow or google, someone must have encountered similar problems before.