# How do I insert a Div after a Class using Jquery or Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't have access to change the HTML.
I'm either wanted to either:

- change the text in the  or
- Hide that Div via CSS (I know how to do this) and add another div under the  to add my own text.

```
     <div class="login-welcome">

                 <img src=" border="0" class="login-logo" alt="">

             <h2>Password recovery</h2> 
             <div class="info">
                 Please enter your username and we will send a password reset link to your email. If you can't remember what your username is please contact your administrator. If you don't have an email address registered with us you will need to contact your administrator to get your password reset. 
             </div>           
     </div>

     <div class="login-form">
         <form action="/account/forgot" method="post"><input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="_1">

         <div class="login-field" tabindex="0"> 
             <label for="Username" style="display:none;">Username</label>
             <input class="form-control input-lg" id="Username" name="Username" placeholder="Username" required="true" type="text" value="">
         </div>
         <div class="login-button" tabindex="1">
             <input type="submit" class="btn btn-login btn-lg" id="continue" value=" Continue ">
         </div>

         <div class="login-forgot">
             or <a href="/account/login">Back to login</a>
         </div>
         </form>
     </div>
 </div>
```

I've tried the following code - but it didn't work.

```js
  
$(document).ready(function(){
if(window.location.pathname == '/account/forgot'){
$( ".info" ).append( $( "<p>Test</p>" ) );
}
});
```

All help is appreciated!

Comment: class selector starts with a `.` for example: `.login-form`
In your example there is no such thing as `forgotPasswordContainer`

Comment: Sorry but I'm confused by the meaning of `insert a Div after a Class`. Could you please explain more regarding to context? And with jQuery `append()`, the agrument that it takes is of the `string` type. I don't quite get what you are trying to do

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to replace innerHTML of a div using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309452/how-to-replace-innerhtml-of-a-div-using-jquery)

Comment: @vanowm Class selector thanks. Unfortunately it still doesn't work. And apologies. I've updated the code to show correct class now.

Comment: @HuyPhạm I need to change the text "Please enter your username and we will send a password etc..." but I can't figure out how to. I don't have access to he direct HTML.

Comment: @A.Meshu I wish it did. But I tried that too and it's also not working.

Comment: you still missing the `.` in your class selector. `$(".info")`

Comment: @vanowm even with the `.` it's not working.

Comment: I know it is very late , but the problem  is in your jQuery , use `jQuery()` instead  of `$` , but their is one more issue in your `append` statement  it need to be  `jQuery( ".info" ).append(  "<p>Test</p>" );`.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

there is an issue in your JavaScript code , for selecting class you need to add `.` with class in jquery like `$('.myclass').hide()` and for selecting id you need to add `#` with id like `$('#myid').hide()`  and for selecting tag  you need to do something that `$("div").hide()`... this is the basic concept of selecting specific `tag , class or id`  in jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
if(window.location.pathname == '/account/forgot'){
$( ".info" ).append("<p>Test</p>" );
}
});
```

the above code will only work on url `/account/forgot` so for testing you need to open that specific `url`

Comment: Thanks Basir. Unfortunately it's still not working. I'm definitely testing on `/account/forgot`

Comment: @campbell do you see any error on console?

Comment: Nope nothing. It's weird. Correct me if I'm wrong but the above should work yeah?